# Difference between closures and lambdas?

Tags: c#, python, ruby, computer-science, theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a 'closure' and a 'lambda'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda)

Hello, World!

Forgive me if this is a tad of a newb q, but everyone always gets computersciencey about it..

What actually is a lambda? And what is a Closure?

As far as I understand a lambda is an anonymous function and a closure is a pointer to the variables of a lambdas parent scope.. (like a snapshot of the variables of the function it was declared in)

How correct is this?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: You may want to accept some of the answers that have been provided to you (especially because it seems like there are some good ones). You will be more likely to get answers to your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

That is totally correct. The term closure is describing the scope thing, the term lambda is describing the whole function as an object thing.