# how to pass parameters of a function when using timeit.Timer()

Tags: python, timer

This is the outline of a simple program

```
# some pre-defined constants
A = 1
B = 2

# function that does something critical
def foo(num1, num2):
    # do something

# main program.... do something to A and B
for i in range(20):
    # do something to A and B
    # and update A and B during each iteration

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="foo(num1,num2)")  
print t.timeit(5)
```

I just keep getting "global name foo is not defined".....
Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Well first of all, the indentation here is confusing. It looks like `foo` is being defined in a different scope than `t`...

Comment: hi. i fixed the indentation. does it look better now? :] thanks.

Comment: timeit is ok for one-liners but for anything else better check this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478351/python-time-measure-function

Comment: There is a very simple solution for this in python3, you can just run the expression in the global namespace by adding the `globals=globals()` parameter to the timeit call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913199/2925963

Comment: **TL;DR**: `duration,return_value=  timeit.Timer(functools.partial(your_function_name, argument_1, argument_2,argument_3)).timeit(1)` where your_function name is `foo` if you write a function like: `def foo(argument_1, argument_2, argument_3):`. Also include the: `timeit.template = """..` block from @Hugh Bothwell. And the `return_value` is what the function returns, for example `argument_1 + argument_2`. And use: `import timeit, functools`. This solution is given by @Jose Ricardo Bustos M.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code snippets must be self-contained - they cannot make external references. You must define your values in the statement-string or setup-string:

```
import timeit

setup = """
A = 1
B = 2

def foo(num1, num2):
    pass

def mainprog():
    global A,B
    for i in range(20):
        # do something to A and B
        foo(A, B)
"""

t = timeit.Timer(stmt="mainprog()" setup=setup)
print(t.timeit(5))
```

Better yet, rewrite your code to not use global values.

Comment: Lucas S. answer makes this one feel kinda wrong. Awkward at least.

Answer (score 97):

The functions can use arguments in `timeit` if these are created using closures, we can add this behaviours by wrapping them in another function.

```
def foo(num1, num2):
    def _foo():
        # do something to num1 and num2
        pass
    return _foo

A = 1
B = 2

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(foo(A,B))  
print(t.timeit(5))
```

or shorter, we can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) instead of explicit closures declaration

```
def foo(num1, num2):
    # do something to num1 and num2
    pass

A = 1
B = 2

import timeit, functools
t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(foo, A, B)) 
print(t.timeit(5))
```

**EDIT using lambda, thanks @jupiterbjy**

we can use lambda function without parameters instead of functools library

```
def foo(num1, num2):
    # do something to num1 and num2
    pass

A = 1
B = 2

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(lambda: foo(A, B)) 
print (t.timeit(5))
```

Comment: Thanks, functools helped me avoid globals, nasty string approach, and the decorator/closure business.

Comment: This snippet works but with real function I get `ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable` (Python 3.6). My function works normally without timeit.

Comment: @Peter.k That is because if you want to just use `timeit.timeit()` it needs to be fed your function as a string for example `timeit.timeit('foo')`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!  Should also note that you don't even need to instantiate a `Timer`; this works also: ```timeit.timeit(functools.partial(foo, A, B), number=5)```

Comment: For current CPython3.8, would calling ```lambda: foo(A, B)``` be bad idea compared to ```functools.partial(foo, A, B)``` for ```timeit```?

Comment: @jupiterbjy you are right, you can use function lambda instead of functools library

Comment: @jupiterbjy [What is the difference between a 'closure' and a 'lambda'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda)

Comment: Didn't know ```partial``` creates closure  - so it's really just up to preferences, I see. Good to know.

Answer (score 16):

Supposing that your module filename is test.py

```
# some pre-defined constants
A = 1
B = 2

# function that does something critical
def foo(n, m):
    pass

# main program.... do something to A and B
for i in range(20):
    pass

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="test.foo(test.A, test.B)", setup="import test")  
print t.timeit(5)
```

Answer (score 12):

I usually create an extra function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return x*y

v1 = 10
v2 = 20

def f_test():
    f(v1,v2)

print(timeit.timeit("f_test()", setup="from __main__ import f_test"))
```

Comment: works only if `v1` and `v2` are globals. If they are local to the f function does not work

Answer (score 9):

Your function needs to be define in the setup string. A good way to do this is by setting up your code in a module, so you simple have to do

```
t = timeit.Timer("foo(num1, num2)", "from myfile import foo")
t.timeit(5)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to define all of the setup as a string inside the setup statement.

```
setup = """
 # some pre-defined constants
A = 1
B = 2

# function that does something critical
def foo(num1, num2):
    # do something

# main program.... do something to A and B
for i in range(20):
    # do something to A and B
    # and update A and B during each iteration
"""

t = timeit.Timer("foo(num1, num2)", setup)
t.timeit(5)
```

Something awesome I just found out about is a shortcut for iPython that uses cProfile.

```
def foo(x, y):
    print x*y

%prun foo("foo", 100)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a much simpler solution (at least for Python 3), you can cause the code to be executed within your current global namespace:

```
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="foo(num1,num2)", globals=globals())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples
I know globals are not preferred, but if you are just making a quick script to check something I think this is the easiest implementation.

Comment: Just be careful with repeats, because results will be cached in the globals.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to bind the function to its arguments via [functools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (similar to std::bind). Then you don't need to pass arguments to timeit, the callable returned by `functool.partial` takes care of that:

```
    def findMax(n):#n is an array
        m = 0
        c = 0
        for i in range(len(n)):
            c += 1
            if m < n[i]:
                m = n[i]
        return m, c


import timeit
import functools
a = [6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 4, 5]
t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(findMax,a))
t.timeit(100)
```

Comment: To me this is by far the simplest solution. It also works with class functions =) Any drawbacks/side-effects?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to compartmentalize the timing routine, without calling globals

```
def foo(a, b):
    '''Do something to `a` and `b`'''
    return a + b

def time_foo():
    '''Create timer object simply without using global variables'''
    import timeit

    _foo = foo
    a = 1
    b = 2

    # Get `Timer` oject, alternatively just get time with `timeit.timeit()`
    t = timeit.Timer('_foo(a, b)', globals=locals())

    return t
```

You could even generalize this if you wanted to use the same `timeit` function to time other functions. Here is an example with your example `main()` routine:

```
def foo1(a, b):
    '''Add `a` and `b`'''
    return a + b

def foo2(a, b):
    '''More math on `a` and `b`'''
    return (a**2 * b)**2

def time_foo(func, **kwargs):
    '''Create timer object simply without using global variables'''
    import timeit
    return timeit.timeit('func(**kwargs)', globals=locals())

def run():
    '''Modify inputs to foo and see affect on execution time'''

    a = 1
    b = 2
    for i in range(10):
        # Update `a` and `b`
        a += 1
        b += 2
        # Pass args to foo as **kwargs dict
        print('foo1 time: ', time_foo(foo1, **{'a':a, 'b':b}))
        print('foo2 time: ', time_foo(foo2, **{'a':a, 'b':b}))

    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import timeit

def f(x,y):
    return x*y

x = 5
y = 7

print(timeit.timeit(stmt='f(x,y)',
                    setup='from __main__ import f, x, y',
                    number=1000))
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest/shortest way to do it along with the lambda method.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating a `static` class with all the Data ready to be picked up prior of running the timer.

> Another note, it is better to do test runs in  function rather then in the global space, as the global space isn't taking advantage of `FAST_LOAD` [Why does Python code run faster in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)

```
class Data(object):
    """Data Creation"""
    x = [i for i in range(0, 10000)]
    y = tuple([i for i in range(0, 10000)])
    def __init__(self):
        pass

import timeit

def testIterator(x):
    for i in range(10000):
        z = i


print timeit.timeit("testIterator(Data.x)", setup="from __main__ import testIterator, Data", number=50)
print timeit.timeit("testIterator(Data.y)", setup="from __main__ import testIterator, Data", number=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with timing in Python 3.7 today and trying to pass functions and variables into the timer. This is what I came up with.

```
import re

text = "This         is      a  test of the      emergency broadcast       system"

def regex(text):
    return re.sub(r"(\s)\1{1,}", r"\1", text)

def loop_while(text):
    if "  " in text:
        while "  " in text:
            text = text.replace("  ", " ")

    return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    callable_functions = [item for item in locals().items() if callable(item[1])]

    for func_name, func in callable_functions:
        elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(f"{func_name}(text)", globals=globals(), number=100000)
        print(f"{func_name}: {elapsed_time} \n{func(text)}\n")
```

This outputs:

> regex: 1.378352418
>   This is a test of the emergency broadcast system
>
> loop_while: 0.15858950299999997
>   This is a test of the emergency
>   broadcast system

Then all it takes to test a new version is adding in a new function. Something like:

```
def split_join(text):
    return " ".join(text.split())
```

Now it outputs:

> regex: 1.378352418
>   This is a test of the emergency broadcast system
>
> loop_while: 0.15858950299999997
>   This is a test of the emergency broadcast system
>
> split_join: 0.05700970800000005
>   This is a test of the emergency broadcast system

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the variable within the setup string. Here I import the function, and create one of the variables that i pass to it. I also set one of the variables by casting it to the stmt string

```
SETUP = '''
from __main__ import policy_iteration
from environments.gridworld import GridworldEnv

env = GridworldEnv()
'''

discount = 5
timeit.timeit("policy_iteration(env,discount_factor="+str(discount)+")",
                          setup= SETUP,
                          number=10))
```