# Figure out how much memory an operation takes

Tags: python

How would I figure out how much memory an operation takes? For example:

```
memory_start = memory()
reader = csv.reader(file)
memory_end = memory()
memory_of_reader = math.abs(memory_end - memory_start)
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478351/python-time-measure-function ?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Comment: @Kasra -- yea that seems a bit advanced, is there a simpler way to just get a single statement's (variable) memory consumption?

Comment: @Hockey127 checkout my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the size of an object you can use [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) that return the size of an object in bytes.

> **sys.getsizeof(object[, default])**
>
> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.
>
> If given, default will be returned if the object does not provide means to retrieve the size. Otherwise a `TypeError` will be raised.
>
> `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

example :

```
>>> import sys
>>> a=2
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
24
>>> a='this is a test'
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
51
```

And for more advanced tasks you can use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) that is a module for monitoring memory usage of a python program

Comment: Would doing `a.__sizeof__()` do the same thing?

Comment: @Hockey127 Indeed,as says in wiki explanation!