# Why does a shared object library compiled with Rust run slower with ctypes?

Tags: python, rust, ctypes

Taking this [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/rust-inside-other-languages.html#python), I improperly wrote a function that calculates the power of a number in Rust, compiled it to a shared object and used it in Python. Then I have written the same algorithm with Python. I tested both and Python seems to be much faster.

#### sum.rs (it was supposed to sum, I changed my mind later)

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn powerof(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut c: i32 = a;
    for x in 0..b {
        c = c*a;
    }
    return c;
}
```

#### trial.py

```py
from ctypes import cdll
import time

_powerof = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libsum.so")

def timing(f):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/5478448
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('{} function took {:0.4f} ms'.format(f.__name__, (time2-time1)*1000.0))
        return ret
    return wrap

@timing
def powerof(a, b):
    global _powerof
    result = _powerof.powerof(a, b)
    return int(result)

@timing
def powerof_python(a, b):
    c = a
    for i in range(b):
        c=c*a
    return c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(powerof(4,5))
    print(powerof(2,3))
    print(powerof(6,4))

    print(powerof_python(4,5))
    print(powerof_python(2,3))
    print(powerof_python(6,4))
```

I have written and compiled Rust in *the most primitive way* (which means, without `cargo`).This is how I compiled Rust code above:

```
rustc sum.rs --crate-type dylib
```

The results are as below:

#### 1st Test

```
powerof function took 0.0780 ms
4096
powerof function took 0.0136 ms
16
powerof function took 0.0064 ms
7776
powerof_python function took 0.0110 ms
4096
powerof_python function took 0.0041 ms
16
powerof_python function took 0.0050 ms
7776
```

## 2nd Test

```
powerof function took 0.0820 ms
4096
powerof function took 0.0083 ms
16
powerof function took 0.0057 ms
7776
powerof_python function took 0.0110 ms
4096
powerof_python function took 0.0041 ms
16
powerof_python function took 0.0041 ms
7776
```

## 3rd Test

```
powerof function took 0.0772 ms
4096
powerof function took 0.0098 ms
16
powerof function took 0.0069 ms
7776
powerof_python function took 0.0129 ms
4096
powerof_python function took 0.0036 ms
16
powerof_python function took 0.0043 ms
7776
```

It seems that the same method runs much faster in Python. Why is that?

---

### Update: Timing within Rust

I edited content of `sum.rs` as below (added main function):

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn powerof(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut c: i32 = a;
    for x in 0..b {
        c = c*a;
    }
    return c;
}

fn main() {
    let a = powerof(4,5);
    let b = powerof(2,3);
    let c = powerof(6,4);

    println!("{}",a);
    println!("{}",b);
    println!("{}",c);
}
```

Compiled it with:

```
rustc sum.rs
```

Then run it with `time` in Linux, as below (after `chmod +x ./sum`):

```
time -v ./sum
```

#### Test 1

```
real    0m2.035s
user    0m0.140s
sys     0m0.072s
```

#### Test 2

```
real    0m0.176s
user    0m0.128s
sys     0m0.040s
```

#### Test 3

```
real    0m0.184s
user    0m0.136s
sys     0m0.044s
```

### With `rustc -O` option

Compiled as below and given executable permission:

```
rustc -O sum.rs
```

#### Test 1

```
real    0m0.169s
user    0m0.132s
sys     0m0.032s
```

#### Test 2

```
real    0m0.207s
user    0m0.148s
sys     0m0.048s
```

#### Test 3

```
real    0m0.170s
user    0m0.124s
sys     0m0.040s
```

---

### Environment

- Python 3.5.2
- Rust 1.7.0

Comment: My guess is that some of the overhead is caused by Python having to convert values to and from `ctypes` compatible types, and [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html#index-3) seems to agree with that. Might be worth comparing a function in Rust that just returns the input with the Python equivalent to see if that may be the case.

Comment: Thanks for answer... :) | As I understood correctly, I should return a Python compatible data (probably with cpython) in Rust. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use cpython, so it might take some time to learn, test and finally update this question.

Comment: Well, I'm not certain, which is why I suggest you test to see if my guess is correct. There probably isn't a lot you can do to avoid the overhead with the `ctypes` module - there will naturally be *some* cost when you convert from one type to another, though I am surprised it's about 0.05s in some cases.

Comment: Thanks again. :) I will go and read some documentations right away.

Comment: Why are you `chmod +x`? The produced binary is already executable.

Comment: Just habits... There were a friend here, and suddenly vanished. Where is he? (Deleted his comments.)

Comment: Yep, comments aren't for long discussion. After you updated the question, I deleted them because they were just noise. Just like I'll delete these after a while.

Comment: Are you on a very slow computer, or one that is otherwise resource-limited? Running the pure Rust code for me takes 12ms, not >150ms like your results.

Comment: Note that you have linked to the documentation for Rust **1.2.0** and that the current version is **1.13.0**. Performance improvements and improved APIS happen all the time, so it's worth keeping up-to-date.

Comment: Yeah, I am on a slow computer. | Yeah, updates might be the issue, too. It was just curiosity came this far.