# python programming time occurrence detection

Tags: python, sqlite

I am doing gender and emotion classification using python programming and I want to save results in sqlite databases...A piece of code is following:
text2 = emotion_mode + " " + gender_mode

```
    tstmp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    fps.update()
    fps.stop()
    t = fps.elapsed()
    if text2 == last_row1:
       continue
    else:
       last_row1 = text2
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (gender,emotion,time,start,end) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" ,(gender_mode,emotion_mode,date,t,t1))
    conn.commit()

bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('window_frame', bgr_image)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

emotion_mode and gender_mode is for example (angry man and etc...)
I want to get t and t1 :t=time that start angry man and t1:time that end angry man and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the time between two events, you can use [`time`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5478448/4464653) from [Mike Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656769/mike-lewis):

```
import time
time1 = time.time()
waitForAngryMenToGetHappy()
time2 = time.time()
print('took %0.3f ms' %((time2-time1)*1000.0))
```

Comment: no i want to count frames that for example angry man occured.,(how insert in code?)

Comment: could you provide an example, what you want your output to look like?

Comment: Yes...i want to when gender/emotion detected then save time of occurence saved..i have this that it is datetime.datetime.now in code..but i have'nt difference of between two situation (for example angry man and happy man) that whats time elapsed angry man occuranced.

Comment: @roiksail: sorry, I can't follow that - could you bring up an example?