# executing two class methods at the same time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am sure many similar questions have been asked before, but after reading many of them I am still not very sure what I should do. So, I have a Python script to control some external instruments (a camera and a power meter). I have written class for both instruments by calling the C functions in the .dll files using ctypes. Right now it looks something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    power_reading = newport.get_reading(N=100,interval=1) # take power meter reading
    img = camera.capture(N=10)
    value = image_processing(img) # analyze the img (ndarray) to get some values
    results.append([power_reading,value]) # add both results to a list
```

I want to start executing the first two lines at the same time. Both `newport.get_reading` and `camera.capture` take about 100ms-1s to run (they will run for the same time if I choose the correct arguments). I don't need them to start at EXACTLY the same time, but ideally the delay should be smaller than about 10-20% of the total run time (so less than 0.2s delay when take each take about 1s to run). From what I have read, I can use the `multiprocessing` module. So I try something like this based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce):

```
def p_get_reading(newport,N,interval,return_dict):
    reading = newport.get_reading(N,interval,return_dict)
    return_dict['power_meter'] = reading

def p_capture(camera,N,return_dict):
    img = camera.capture(N)
    return_dict['image'] = img

for i in range(10):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=p_capture, args=(camera,10))
    p.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=p_get_reading, args=(newport,100,1))
    p2.start()
    p.join()
    p2.join()
    print(return_dict)
```

I have a few problems/questions:

1. I need to get the return values from both function calls. Using my current method, `return_dict` is only showing the entry for `capture_img` but not the power meter reading, why is that? It also read that I can use `Queue`, what is the best method for my current purpose?
2. How can I know whether both functions indeed start running at the same time? I am thinking of using the `time` module to record both the start and end time of both functions, maybe using some wrapper function to do the time logging, but will the use of `multiprocessing` pose any restrictions?
3. I usually run my code on an IDE (spyder), and from what I have read, I need to run in command prompt to see the output (I have some print statements inside the functions for debugging purposes). Can I still run in IDE for having both functions run at the same time?

Comment: One thing that may skew your experiments is the creation of `Process` objects: The time can be significant. So, you may need to create the processes first, and only once they are created, they could be released to do their jobs. Some form of mutex or lock might do it. Or a `Queue` could help.

Comment: 1. This seems to be a problem on your site with the reading function, because i'm not able to reproduce it. Maybe add code so we can reproduce it. 2. Shouldn't be a problem. multiprocessing just wants a callable, so it doesn't care about wrappers, (but don't use global variables). time.time is also not constrained. 3. I have zero idea because i work with pycharm, where it works from ide as well.

Comment: 1. try `dict.update({'key':'value'})`, it may help with async processing; 2. you can use `time`-module (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478351/python-time-measure-function/5478448#5478448)), but I would **not** recommend it, since you are "wasting" more time between you actions, while doing it; 3. try to use `sys.stdout.write()`; 4. as quamrana said, create `p`and `p2` first, then execute : `p.start()` and `p2.start()`

Answer (score 3):

Using a `Lock` may help with synchronisation:

```
import multiprocessing

def p_get_reading(newport, N, interval, lock, return_dict):
    lock.acquire()
    lock.release()
    reading = newport.get_reading(N, interval)
    return_dict['power_meter'] = reading

def p_capture(camera, N, lock, return_dict):
    lock.acquire()
    lock.release()
    img = camera.capture(N)
    return_dict['image'] = img

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    for i in range(10):
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        lock.acquire()
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=p_capture, args=(camera,10,lock,return_dict))
        p.start()
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=p_get_reading, args=(newport,100,1,lock,return_dict))
        p2.start()
        lock.release()
        p.join()
        p2.join()
        print(return_dict)
```

The two `Process` objects can now be created and `start()`ed in any order as the main routine has already acquired the lock. Once released, the two processes will fight between themselves to acquire and release the lock, and be ready *almost* at the same time.

Also, note the use of `if __name__ == "__main__"` as this helps when `multiprocessing` makes new processes.

I must say this seems like an abuse of a `Lock`

Answer (score 1):

An **answer to your first question** is simply no if you are doing in normal way, but yes if you want it to be. No because the target function cannot communicate back to spawning thread using a `return`. One way to do it is to use a queue and wrapper functions as following:

```
from threading import Thread 
from Queue import Queue 

def p_get_reading(newport,N,interval,return_dict):
   reading = newport.get_reading(N,interval,return_dict)
   return_dict.update({'power_meter': reading})
   return return_dict

def p_capture(camera,N,return_dict):
   img = camera.capture(N) 
   return_dict.update({'image': img})
   return return_dict

def wrapper1(func, arg1, arg2, queue):
   queue.put(func(arg1, arg2)) 

def wrapper2(func, arg1, arg2, arg3, queue):
    queue.put(func(arg1, arg2, arg3)) 

q = Queue()
Thread(target=wrapper1, args=(p_capture, camera, 10 , q)).start() 
Thread(target=wrapper2, args=(p_get_reading, newport, 100, 1, q)).start()
```

Now `q` holds the updated and  returned `dict` from `p_capture()` and `p_get_reading()`.

Comment: but do I still get the synchronisation with `threading` (at least in theory)? I tried putting `start_time = time.perf_counter()` before `reading=newport.get_reading()` and `img=camera_capture`, and output the the start time through the `return_dict`. The time delay is about 0.004s (which is within my tolerence), but how much should I trust this number? Will the two lines `reading=newport.get_reading()` and `img=camera_capture` actually start with a much larger time delay?

Comment: You can use `threading` to perform multiple I/O tasks or execute multiple functions. Theory wise they are synchronised and executes at same time but there will be time delay for sure. If you are using multi-core system, you may take advantage of that instead. `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` might help here.