# Measuring performance of multiple functions through a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, performance, function, time

I have multiple functions and I want to measure the performance of each and store elapsed time in a list. I am a bit confused about running these functions in the time measure function:

```
def time_measure(function):
    import time
    t = time.process_time()
    # run function here
    elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
    output = []
    output.append(elapsed time)
    return output
```

or I think I can just run `time_measure` for each of the functions and get the time measurements separately. I have five functions to run.

How do I run the function within the `time_measure` function, and set the function as a parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python time measure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478351/python-time-measure-function)

Comment: If that's for benchmarking, you may want to check the stdlib's `timeit` module. If that's for profiling, better use a real profiler...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to measure the time of a function in **iPython** and you don't need to write any code.

Start **iPython** and enter your code:

```
import time 

def SomeFunction(): 
    time.sleep(0.337)
    return
```

Now you can time calls to that function:

```
%timeit SomeFunction()
339 ms ± 1.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If you want to time multiple statements, use `%%timeit`:

```
%%timeit 
     SomeFunction() 
     SomeFunction() 
     SomeFunction() 

1.02 s ± 2.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```