# call a time-sensitive fail-safe function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a time-sensitive request, let's call it `query_response`.

How to write the program so that, if `query_response` take less than 2 seconds then run `take_action` else run `abort_action`.

```
def query_response():
  print("Query Response")

def take_action():
  print("Take Action") 

def abort_action():
  print("Abort Action")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python time measure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478351/python-time-measure-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you can do is save the time that your function started at and subtract the start_time from the time that your function ended at. For example: if your query_response started 12:34 and ended 12:37, you would get an execution time of 3 minutes. Code:

```
import time

def query_response():
  start_time = time.time() # Save the time your function started
  print("Query Response")
  time_passed = time.time() - start_time # Save the total execution time
                                         # of your function
  if time_passed > 2: take_action()
  else: abort_action()

def take_action():
  print("Take Action") 

def abort_action():
  print("Abort Action")
```