# timeit throwing keyerror in Python

Tags: python, timeit

I am trying to time a simple Python method using timeit but I keep getting the following error

```
File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
KeyError: 'tree'
```

The code, as shown below, creates a 'tree' object and then I attempt to pass that object in the Timer object.  I guess this is where the problem is.

Note that if instead I pass binarytree.mkthing(0,10) to Timer the code works.  However doing this calls mkthing at every pass.  I want to call it only once and then reuse it.

How should I go about doing that?

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    tree = mkthing(0,10)

    t1=timeit.Timer("binarytree.traverse_asc(locals()['tree'],binarytree.printout)","import binarytree")
    print t1.repeat(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:  `from __main__ import tree` in the setup code:

```
t1 = timeit.Timer("binarytree.traverse_asc(tree,binarytree.printout)",
                  setup = "import binarytree; from __main__ import tree")
```

Or better yet, move the making of the thing (`tree`) into the setup code all-together:

```
t1 = timeit.Timer("binarytree.traverse_asc(tree,binarytree.printout)",
                  setup = "import binarytree; tree = mkthing(0,10)")
```

Answer (score 0):

timeit.Timer evals the statement you pass it in inside the timeit module. It can't access the tree variable.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086430/how-to-pass-parameters-of-a-function-when-using-timeit-timer) is somewhat related and should help you get the gist.