# What is lambda?

Tags: javascript, lambda, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a 'closure' and a 'lambda'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda)

Hello everyone!

I'm a JavaScript developer. I know what is closure and how it works in JavaScript.

But today I see a new noun "lambda". What is lambda? It appears to be relevant to closure in JavaScript. What's the difference between lambda and closure in JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus):

> In mathematical logic and computer science, lambda calculus, also written as λ-calculus, is a formal system for function definition, function application and recursion.

Look at Motivation, under Informal description