# Scope of Lambda Expression Method to Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, events, lambda

If I define a variable within a method, then subscribe to an event with a Lambda expression, and use the variable within the body of that expression, is the reference still valid? I don't get a compile time error, but it doesn't seem to be working quite as I'd hoped, either.

See:

```
void OnAddAssignment()
{
    var win = new View.NewTransportationView();
    var vm = new NewTransportationViewModel(DateTime.Today);
    vm.JobSaved += (s, e) => { win.Close(); };

    win.DataContext = new ViewModel.NewTransportationViewModel(DateTime.Today);
    win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

    win.Show();
}
```

Note: `NewTransportationView` inherits from `System.Windows.Window`

I was hoping when `JobSaved` fires, the window would close, and I wouldn't have to save the reference to the `NewTransportationView` outside the method.

I realize there are probably dozens of other ways to solve this problem, many or most more elegant and efficient, and while I am certainly open to seeing suggestions, I am more interested in the general behavior and scope rules for this particular application of a Lambda expression.

Bonus question: where do my Window objects live when I call `.Show()` on them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures

Comment: Did you mean to assign a different instance of the `NewTransportationViewModel` class to the `win.DataContext` property?

Comment: @RichardDeeming NOPE! I just noticed this when I returned to my code. Probably in about the same instance of your comment. ;)

Comment: @L.B Excellent link. Thank you. Did get that with my terms of 'lambda' & 'scope'

Comment: Well, as soon as I fixed my reference oversight, it works as I'd expected it to, resolving my problem, answering my question, and expanding my knowledge. win, win, win.

Comment: @Michael For reference, this isn't inelegant at all.  It's my favorite approach for solving this type of problem because it works, it clear to the reader, and honestly about as elegant of a solution as I've ever seen.  It also comes up quite often.  Closures FTW.