# Event pass parameter

Tags: c#, events

I have problem with event. For example let i have event
 `public event EventHandler<AxisChangedEventArgs> AxisChanged` 
which fires when Axis pan or zoom or something else. When it's firing i am making `Console.WriteLine("Working");`. How can i pass `CFDBOX` parameter into `SomeWork` anonymous method does not help because it will be imposible to unsubscribe from it. And i cannot override `AxisChanged` event.

```
public void AddEvents(CFDBOX CFDBOX) {
    CFDBOX.PlotModel.Axes[0].AxisChanged += SomeWork;
}

public void RemoveEvents(CFDBOX CFDBOX) {
    CFDBOX.PlotModel.Axes[0].AxisChanged -= SomeWork;
}

public EventHandler<AxisChangedEventArgs> SomeWork =
    delegate(object o, AxisChangedEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Working");
    }
;
```

Comment: Check what is sent in `object o`. It could be either `PlotModel` or `CFDBOX`

Comment: Do you have a way to identify the `CFDBOX` from a given `Axis`? You've got two options, you can find a way to do that, and in your handler, get it, or call `AxisChanged` from the `CFDBOX` itself (instead of from `CFDBOX.PlotModel.Axes[0]`) and then find which axis has changed some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9591622/3071928) lambda expressions:

```
private EventHandler<AxisChangedEventArgs> axisChangedEventHandler;

public void AddEvent(CFDBOX CFDBOX) {
    // keep a reference of the event handler to remove it later
    axisChangedEventHandler = (o, args) => {
        // parameter CFDBOX bound to the event handler
        Console.WriteLine("Working " + CFDBOX); 
    };
    // register event handler
    CFDBOX.PlotModel.Axes[0].AxisChanged += axisChangedEventHandler;
}

public void RemoveEvent() {
    // unregister event handler
    CFDBOX.PlotModel.Axes[0].AxisChanged -= axisChangedEventHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any parameter which must be passed with an `event` should be a member of your `EventArgs` implementation. In your scenario: `AxisChangedEventArgs`. Hope i get your question.

The sender of the event (in your case `o`) should always be the instance, which calls the event. So if your event get's fired from different classes (not instances!), you will have to check for the type of `o`.