# Discrepancy in C# LINQ results

Tags: c#, .net

When I do this:

```
currentPage = metadataResponse.ApplicationType.Pages.Find(
   page => page.SortOrder == ++currentPage.SortOrder);
```

The value of `currentPage` is null.

But the same logic, when I assign the increment value to an integer variable, and then try to get the `currentPage`

```
int sortOrder = ++currentPage.SortOrder;
currentPage = metadataResponse.ApplicationType.Pages.Find(
    page => page.SortOrder == sortOrder);
```

`currentPage` gets populated.

Does anyone have a good answer as to why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: They're not equivalent, simple as that.  Apparently the lambda is being evaluated multiple times (I don't know what the `Find()` method is) and is changing the current page's sort order multiple times.

Comment: Avoid lambda expressions with side effects in queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note:* I assume `Find` method is applied to a collection of values.

In the first code example, you are incrementing `currentPage` for each element in your collection (this is happening because lambda expressions introduce closures over variables captured from outer scope - see below code block for more info about that). In the second code example, `currentPage` is incremented only once. Take a look how the following program behaves:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func1();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Func2();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Func1()
    {
        int i = 0;
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(++i));
    }

    private static void Func2()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = ++i;
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(j));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures) is some more info about closures in lambda expressions. Have fun! ;-)