# Confusion about value capturing in C# lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

To illustrate my confusion, see the following example:

```
int a = 0;
Action act = () => ++a;
act();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

I have difficulty figuring out how modification to the captured variable within the lambda could possibly affect the local variable `a`. First of all, the implicitly generated lambda function object could not store a reference to the local variable `a`. Otherwise, if `act` is returned and invoked later, the referenced local variable `a` would already be vanished. A solution to this problem would be copy-by-value, either by copying the `int` value directly or through boxing, so that the function object would have its own copy the local variable `a`. But this doesn't explain the example just given. So, what is the underlying mechanism? Would it be that the seemingly local variable `a` is actually no longer a local variable, but translated by the compiler to be a reference to an `int` field within the generated lambda function object?

Comment: An inner class in created: http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3azsASHmRkMKjAC8MAAw5FAQVLIwfCKsMaYkjQD4YAajtVd8qocnP6JkHyKoAdADqAE5gaAAykKhiVBKYsnLx7DJsAL7YKUAA

Comment: `but translated by the compiler to be a reference to an int field within the generated lambda function object?` Spot-on guess :)

Comment: @Dennis_E I know that. The real question is: is `a` at the first line a local variable of type `int` or just a reference into an `int` field of the generated lambda function object which is an instance of the inner class?

Comment: @Lingxi Check out the converted code. It moves `a` into a new class, and when you write `Console.WriteLine(a)`, it converts it to use the lambda-object's `a` instead.

Comment: In C++ you have to explicitly reference all variables you want to use, in C# it (a) is automatically in scope.

Comment: Your last sentence says it: `a` is no longer a local variable, but a field of this new inner class.

Comment: @Dennis_E, exactly

Comment: @Rob With a C++ background, I'm really surprised by the way C# implements lambda capture.

Comment: They had their reasons for doing it this way. I remember an article about this, but of course I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures). After compilation `a` is not a local variable anymore - it's a field of auto-generated class, both in function scope and in lambda.