# C# Action Variable Scope and Null References

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I can declare an Action and pass it a method on an instance object which modifies that object's internal state, then call the method and see that the private instance variables have changed. But if I create the Action, then null out the object it has a reference to a method on I don't get a null reference exception when I invoke the Action, but obviously I do if I try to access the object.

How can it be changing anything if there is nothing there to change?

A contrived example where I create a builder object which has a public void BuildWall method which just increments the number of walls it has built (a private integer variable). Why can I call buildWallAction after I have set builder to null or else how is the Action modifying the object if the object doesn't need to exist in order to call the action?

Thanks in advance :)

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Builder builder = new Builder("Jim");
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        Action buildWallAction = builder.BuildWall;
        builder = null; //no more builder to change via BuildWall()
        //starts work

        buildWallAction();  //these calls modify _wallsBuilt on the builder object 
        buildWallAction();  //but if we set it to null we can still call them just fine

        Console.WriteLine(builder.GetBuildingStatus()); //we will only get an exception here if builder is null
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Builder
{
    private string _name;
    private int _wallsBuilt;
    public Builder(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _wallsBuilt = 0;
    }

    public void BuildWall()
    {
        _wallsBuilt++;
    }

    public string GetBuildingStatus()
    {
        string msg = $"{_name} has built {_wallsBuilt} walls.";
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: The action captures the `builder` variable as a closure - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `builder` variable isn't **the instance**, it is a **reference to the instance**. So setting the variable to `null`, doesn't 'erase' the instance, you only get rid of the reference so you cannot access it anymore.

The `buildWallAction` variable is a reference to the method `BuildWall` of the instance. This is no way directly related to the `builder` variable. Setting the `builder` variable to `null` doesn't do anything to the `buildWallAction` variable.