# How to deal with the "Access to modified closure" warning

Tags: c#

Given the following code snippet:

```
string body = "blabla";

/* some processing */

itinerary.Propositions.Each(prop =>
{
    /* some processing */
    body += "looking good";

    /* some more processing */
});
```

Resharper is throwing the "Access on a local closure" error. Now, I've read a lot about this, but so far not a way to avoid the error in situations like this.

So... how can I still use the variable body without having the warning?

Comment: Is this the exact error message? I find it strange for resharper to use `closure` in the context of lambdas

Comment: @MatanShahar, it is not strange that resharper complains. Resharper doesn't know if the code inside `itinerary.Propositions.Each` that will invoke the delegate is being executed synchronously or asynchronously in some way...

Comment: Well, I should add I'm only getting this warning since installing a plugin which "completes" some of the testing by Resharper. I understand the theory, just wonder how I can avoid getting the warning.

Comment: @elgonzo I'm not saying that the error itself is unlikely, the wording seems off so I ask for the error verbatim.

Comment: @MatanShahar, the wording is not off. Some background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures

Comment: "Access to modified closure" Appologies. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are modifying a variable within a lambda that is declared outside the lambda, which is a warning. So either ignore the warning or don't modify it within a lambda. If you understand *why* it's a warning then you'll be in a better position to know if you *should* ignore the warning or not.

> how can I still use the variable body without having the warning?

Just use `foreach`?

```
foreach (var prop in itinerary.Propositions)
{
    /* some processing */
    body += "looking good";

    /* some more processing */
}
```

Comment: Is `body` used somewhere else within another lambda? With what you've posed there _are_ no closures.

Comment: Yes, I've already thought of that. But it would mean a "drastic" change in the code base and it would be probably not be approved. As ridiculous as it may sound...

Comment: You need to provide more context so we can understand why this is a "drastic" change and provide a different solution.

Comment: Ow well... the code reviewer here doesn't like it when you change constructs with no good reason. I don't have to change anything in this part of the code, so a small change would be accepted, but changing the flow by introducing a new construct is not.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are building a string, a loop with `+=` is not optimal. It creates a lot of new immutable instances to be garbage collected, and can be rewritten in a more beautiful way.

Maybe:

```
string body = "blabla" + string.Concat(itinerary.Propositions
  .Select(prop => { /* some processing */ return "looking good"; })
  );
```

If delimiters are desired, use `string.Join` instead of `string.Concat`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just disable warning:

```
// ReSharper disable once AccessToModifiedClosure
body += "looking good";
```

or Alt+Enter on "body", then

[image]