# C# Tasks.Run, local var not given to Task? Bug?

Tags: c#

Got a strange bug.

The output of following is:

```
RANGE: 100000 - 125000
RANGE: 100000 - 125000
RANGE: 100000 - 125000
RANGE: 100000 - 125000
```

And this is wrong!
If I add an extra local `var` in the loop, the output is right!

```cs
int ax = i;
var curtask = Task.Run(() =>Work(ax, blocksize, size));
```

Output:

```
RANGE: 75000 - 100000
RANGE: 0 - 25000
RANGE: 25000 - 50000
RANGE: 50000 - 75000
```

(it's ok that the order isn't kept)

So the `i` var is not given to the task on creation?
I find this situation very dangerous. Normally I would have trust in the parallels!

```cs
private static void Work(int startIndex, int blocksize, int maxSize)
{
    int end = startIndex + blocksize;
    Trace.WriteLine($"RANGE: {startIndex} - {end}");
    Console.WriteLine($"RANGE: {startIndex} - {end}");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int size = 100000;
    int blocksize = size/4;
    int taskcount = 0;
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    while (i < size)
    {
        //THIS WORKS!!!
        //int ax = i;
        //var curtask = Task.Run(() =>Work(ax, blocksize, size));

        var curtask = Task.Run(() => Work(i, blocksize, size));
        taskcount++;
        tasks.Add(curtask);

        i = i + blocksize;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You've made the common error of closing a lambda over a variable. This behaviour is unexpected to most people, but is correct. See https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Comment: If you do a search here for "C# lambda closed over loop variable" or similar, you will find a great many similar questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Variables that are passed to a task are accessed something like by reference (c# keeps the value of variable updated). So, if you send the variable `i` to each task, its value will be updated for all of your tasks as the loop progresses. You must create a local variable before sending `i` to send a copy of `i` at the current moment to each task. What you are commented in your source code is a correct way to do this.
Here, your all tasks are just started after the ending of the while loop. So, they see the last value of the `i`.

Comment: Almost nothing in this answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Eric for clarification. I updated the answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

All seems right to me. i is captured. You have only one i which is shared by all tasks, but you have many ax's and each of them has different value.

Maybe you can read about closures, for example here: [Are Lambda expressions in C# closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because on `Task.Run` call the created task doesn't run immediately but is created only (`WaitingToRun` status proves this)

[image]

So for example the first created task hasn't started yet but another iteration already happened and `i` is incremented and so on.