# Defer starting of a Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a series of methods (with variable number of parameters) that return a Task
I want to create a method that does something before and after each of this methods, by passing the Task.
I've simplified everything (removed cancellationToken, actual processing, etc) in this sample:

```
public async Task<string> GetDataString()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing");
    return "test";
}


public async Task<T> Process<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    var res = await task;
    Console.WriteLine("After");
    return res;
}
```

And in my main:

```
Task<string> task = GetDataString();
string result = await Process<string>(tasks);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

the console output is

```
Executing
Before
After
test
```

What can I do to create the task but not actually starting it? And starting it only before the wait?

I managed to do it by creating a PauseToken, as explained in this article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/
but I wonder if is there a better way.

Thanks,
Mattia

Comment: Pass a `Func<Task>` instead. This method is used throughout the framework.

Comment: Thanks but I thought about that, but I don't have only GetDataString(), I may have GetDataString2(string param) and GetDataString3(string param, int paramInt). How can I create a generic Process(Func<Task>) method?

Comment: The parameters of the function doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I would need a Process(Func<Task>), Process(Func<string,Task>) a Process(Func<string,int,Task>)

Comment: @tia you were right that parameters of the functions doesn't matter, I guess I didn't fully understand how Func<TResult> Delegate works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your generic `ProcessAsync` method could accept a task factory as argument:

```
public async Task<T> ProcessAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    var res = await taskFactory();
    Console.WriteLine("After");
    return res;
}
```

This way the task will be created at the time you'll invoke the factory method. You are in control of its creation.

Here is an example of calling the `ProcessAsync` method, passing as factory a lambda:

```
var result = await ProcessAsync(() => GetDataStringAsync(arg1, arg2));
```

This way you are not restricted to a factory method without arguments.

For completeness I should mention that `Task` objects can also created in a cold state using the constructor `new Task()`, and started later using the [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method, but this approach is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks! The solution I was looking for. In the meantime I implemented the Task() one by myself but I didn't like it.
What I don't understand is why Func<Task<T>> can pair with GetDataStringAsync(arg1,arg2), shouldn't be declared as Func<string,string,Task<T>>?
I misunderstood how Func<TResult> Delegate works

Comment: The `GetDataStringAsync` is not invoked directly, because that would be inflexible: `await ProcessAsync(GetDataStringAsync, arg1, arg2)`. You would need a different `ProcessAsync` overload for each set of arguments. Instead it's invoked indirectly through a lambda `() => ...` that captures the values of the arguments. If you want to learn more about captured variables and closures look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures).

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the async keyword (from GetDataString) and create a new task which will be executed when you await

so the result of the code below is : before , executing , test , after

```
      private static async Task Start()
        {
            Task<string> task = GetDataString();
            string result = await Process<string>(task);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public Task<string> GetDataString()
        {
            return new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.Default).StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing");
                return "test";
            });
        }


        public async Task<T> Process<T>(Task<T> task)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before");
            var res = await task;
            Console.WriteLine("After");
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: The call to `GetDataString` still returns a hot task which is not what the OP is after.