# Error in Anonymous Method contained variable

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods

I have the following method. When the Writeline Methods are calling, missing results arise. The result of 
the second Writeline must true otherwise, it is false, could you please advise me?

```
    public static void IsGreater()
    {
       var biggerThanNumber = new Predicate<int>[10];
       for (int index = 0; index < biggerThanNumber.Length; ++index)
       {
         biggerThanNumber[index] = value => value > index; 
       }
       Console.WriteLine(biggerThanNumber[5](20)); //True
       Console.WriteLine(biggerThanNumber[5](6));  //False
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Please provide: The input. The expected output. The real output.

Comment: @Christopher OP problem is seems to be clear, because lambda expression captures loop variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method to copy loop variable into a local reference to avoid lambda closure issue in a loop. In your method value of index is always 10 hence second the console is returning false. For more info check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures#:~:text=A%20closure%20is%20%22a%20function,%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20Console.)

```
    public static void IsGreater()
    {
        var biggerThanNumber = new Predicate<int>[10];
        for (int index = 0; index < biggerThanNumber.Length; ++index)
        {
            int localCopy = index;
            biggerThanNumber[index] = value => value > localCopy;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(biggerThanNumber[5](20)); //True
        Console.WriteLine(biggerThanNumber[5](6));  //True
    }
```