# CancellationToken registered callback is called after the token is no longer used

Tags: c#, .net

Skeleton code:

```
 class Thing
 {
    public async Task<int> RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {
            //doesn't accept a cancellation, this kills it
            this.tcpClient.Dispose();
        });
        ...
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
       tcpClient.Dispose();
       tcpClient = null;
    }
 }
```

...

```
var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
var x = new Thing();
await x.RunAsync(cancellation.Token);
x.Dispose();
//yes I know this is odd in this example, it's just to demo
cancellation.Cancel();
```

I discovered that if `RunAsync` has already completed, and the object disposed, then cancelling the associated `CancellationTokenSource` still calls the registered lambda. Unsurprisingly this causes unexpected behaviour - I found the issue since `tcpClient` was set to null by `Dispose()` for example.

Since the method has already exited, why does `cancellationToken` (a value type) still exist at all? It's a good reminder that in C#, objects may exist after you stop using them but I would have thought method-scoped entities *would* have disappeared.

What should be different here? Is `Register` a dangerous method to use or am I just mis-using it?

Comment: A note, in practice there would be lotd of `Thing` objects. Some active, others discarded and disposed - the idea being I can cancel them all, unlike this very simple and a bit odd example.

Comment: The cancellation token doesn't care about where it's used. When the task is cancelled, register is called. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The register method had captured the tcpClient instance via closure, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9591622/11582808

Comment: Have you tried to explictly Dispose the CancellationTokenRegistration? Or in dotnet Core call `Unregister()` at the end of the RunAsync Method?

Comment: `CancelationToken` is a struct, but `CancelationToken.Register` [internally](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/CancellationToken.cs,270) binds to classes.

Comment: @Fildor I had totally missed that it returned `CancellationTokenRegistration` and I'm in .net so hadn't seen there was any way to unregister - thanks I think that's the answer I was after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CancellationToken.Register` returns a disposable `CancellationTokenRegistration`. The registration is ended by disposing it.

So, wrap your registration in a using block, then the callback will no longer be invoked by a Cancel, as soon as the block ended.

```
using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {
            //doesn't accept a cancellation, this kills it
            this.tcpClient.Dispose();
        }))
{
// your code...
}
```

I would still advise to make your code robust in case `this.tcpClient` is null. **I'm not sure**, but if we put a long sleep inside the registered callback and cancel from a separate thread, it might still be possible to start executing the callback and then finishing the `RunAsync`, disposing `Thing` and then reaching the point in callback, where `this.tcpClient` is accessed.