# Unexpected identical object obtained for each http request for scoped service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, minimal-apis

I have two endpoints:

- `/x` that is defined in `Endpoint.Register()` ([Bipin Joshi's approach](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f3dcbb45-fa8b-4e12-b284-f0cd2e5b2dcf.aspx) to organize endpoints)
- `/y` that is defined in `Main()` (the default of minimal api template)

As I expect that instances of `Endpoint` and `Foo` are different for each http request, I register them as `scoped`.

Unfortunately, `Foo` object instantiated in `/x` are always identical for all http requests. It is not what I expect. `Foo` objects instantiated in `/y` are different as expected.

## Question

What causes this issue?

```
public class Foo{}

public class Endpoint
{
    private readonly ILogger<Endpoint> logger;
    private readonly Foo foo;

    public Endpoint(ILogger<Endpoint> logger, Foo foo)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Register(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapGet("/x", () =>
        {
            // it unexpectedly produces the same foo!
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"x: {foo.GetHashCode()}");
            return Results.Ok();
        });
    }
}



public  class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

     
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<Foo>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<Endpoint>();

        var app = builder.Build();


        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Endpoint>()?.Register(app);
        }



        app.MapGet("/y", (ILogger<Endpoint> logger, Foo foo) =>
        {
            // it expectedly produces a different foo for each request.
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, $"y: {foo.GetHashCode()}");
            return Results.Ok();
        });
  

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Bipin Joshi's the sixth approach (see my link above, in which the services are injected in a wrapping class and shared among endpoints) recommended to organize endpoints?

Comment: hashcodes can be reused.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I changed the implementation of `Foo` with random id and the problem still exists. So reusing hashcode must not be the culprit. :-)

Comment: Probably because the scoped services invoked in `Main` are promoted as singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // it unexpectedly produces the same foo!

Actually this is pretty much expected. The following code:

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
   scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Endpoint>()?.Register(app);
}
```

Creates a scope which creates an instance of `Foo` which will be captured by lambda (via [lambda closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures) mechanism) and will be reused for the whole app lifetime (as is observed by you). I.e. the following quote:

> Unfortunately, `Foo` object instantiated in `/x` are always identical for all http requests

is not actually true, there is no `Foo` object instantiated in `/x` handler, it reuses the same instance (note that by default for classes `GetHashCode` is computed based on an [object's reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0#remarks)).

I would argue that this registration method is overengineered, cumbersome, confusing and in some cases outright faulty (as the one in the article which will lead to problems with the reused/shared context) and I would recommend against using it.