# C# LINQ Deferred Execution and Nested Methods

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

I have written the following code:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
int start = 0;
int end = 5;
int limit = 10;
IEnumerable<int> GetRange(List<int> list, int startGR, int endGR)
{
    for (int i = startGR; i < endGR; i++)
    {
        yield return list[i];
    }
}
IEnumerable<int> query = GetRange(ints, start, end).Where(x => x < limit);

void FirstMethod(IEnumerable<int> query1, ref int start1, ref int end1, ref int limit1)
{
    start1 = 4;
    end1 = 9;
    limit1 = 8;
    SecondMethod(query1);

    start1 = 9;
    end1 = 14;
    limit1 = 16;
    SecondMethod(query1);
}

void SecondMethod(IEnumerable<int> query2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", query2));
}

FirstMethod(query, ref start, ref end, ref limit);
```

The console prints:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Instead of expected:

```
5, 6, 7
10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

Please explain why doesn't deferred execution work here with updated values.

Is there a way to make this work as I expect?

Comment: Your initialisation of `query` captures the values of `start` and `end` at the time that it is initialised, so changing their values afterwards has no effect on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetRange(List<int> list, int startGR, int endGR)` will receive copy of passed `start` and `end` upon the invocation (i.e. ["by value"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters)), hence here:

```
IEnumerable<int> query = GetRange(ints, start, end).Where(x => x < limit);
```

after that `ref` manipulations done with `start` and `end` in `FirstMethod` will have no effect, so you will have a `IEnumerable<int>` which will process range from `0` to `5` i.e. the initial values of the variables.

You can try using LINQ with it's deferred execution and the fact that lambda will capture the local variables via [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591476/are-lambda-expressions-in-c-sharp-closures) (as you do with `Where(x => x < limit)`):

```
IEnumerable<int> query = ints
    .Where((_, index) => index >= start && index <= end)
    .Where(x => x < limit);
```

Though personally I'm not a big fun of such approach.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. Why does this happen? Why does GetRange receive a copy of the original values? Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Is this because the GetRange method gets executed right away and stores its' results, and only where gets called by later calls?

Comment: @MichailGolubjev this happens because method parameters are passed by value (see the link in the answer and the usage of `ref` in the `FirstMethod`). _"Is there a way to make this work?"_ - seems to be a bit of XY problem. Why exactly do you want that?

Comment: Well, I've written some code that relies on my assumption, now I will have to rewrite it. Also, I want to understand the correct mechanism. Why does LINQ work with updated variables when using deferred execution, but this code doesn't?

Comment: @MichailGolubjev see the update. It is not LINQ per se but the fact that lambdas use closures to capture variables (see the link in the answer).

Comment: @Guru Stron Instead of 2 where... u can just do ints.Where((v, index) => index >= start && index <= end && v < limit);

Comment: @DA yes, sure, opted to split into separate lines to be more concise with the original code.