# Error Incompatible types: Not able to understand Function<R,T> in the java8

Tags: java, java-8

In the following sample code, I am not able to understand why it is complaining `incompatible types: invalid method reference` for `case II` but not for the `case I`. Though `java.awt.Color::brighter` and `NewBrightColor::brightColor` have similar method signature.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // CASE I
        Function<Color, Color> brighter = Color::brighter;

        // CASE II
        Function<Color, Color> newBrighter = NewBrightColor::brightColor; 

    }

class NewBrightColor {
    public Color brightColor() {
        // return some Bright color
    }
}
```

Edit:

I have taken this example from the presentation https://youtu.be/e4MT_OguDKg?t=31m58s

As per my understanding, `Function<R,T>` should take only those function where input is `R` and output is `T`. But in `case I` it is not true(`Function<Color, Color>` expects Color as input but `brighter()` has input void), but still there is no compilation error but in `case II` it throws compilation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the signature for `Color.brighter`

```
public Color brighter();
```

Now look at your method reference:

```
Function<Color, Color> brighter = Color::brighter;
```

So when I call `brighter.apply(color)` I call `color.brighter` and return the result.

Now look at the method signature for `NewBrightColor.brightColor`:

```
public Color brightColor(Color color)
```

And look at the function reference

```
Function<Color, Color> newBrighter = NewBrightColor::brightColor;
```

When I call `newBrighter.apply(colour)` I need to invoke `brightColor` on an **instance** of `NewBrighter` and return the result.

So I have one argument *missing* - I need a `Color` to make brighter *and** I need the `NewBrightColor` I want to call `brightColor` on, passing in the color.

---

So, you could

1) pass the instance using a `BiFunction`:

```
BiFunction<NewBrightColor, Color, Color> newBrighter = NewBrightColor::brightColor
```

This will, when calling `newBrighter.apply(brighter, color)`, call `brighter.brightColor(color)`.

2) define the `Function` on an instance of `NewBrighter`:

```
NewBrighter nb = //somehow get an instance
Function<Color, Color> newBrighter = nb::brightColor;
```

This will, when calling `newBrighter.apply(color)`, call `nb.brightColor(color)`.

Comment: sorry i did one mistake in sample code.. please check it once again

Comment: could you please look at the question once again. i did mistake first time while posting the question.

Comment: @subhashkumarsingh your error should be obvious if you read and understand this answer.

Comment: I think i understood your answer, but my question is why `case-I` is valid, `Function<Color,Color>` expects input as `Color` but method `java.awt.Color::brighter` has no parameter still we don't get any compilation error. This point I am not able to understand. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: @subhashkumarsingh you're missing the subtle difference between two different types of [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The parameter is the `Color` you want to call `brighter` on.

Answer (score 2):

`Color#brighter()` is no-arg method, while `Function<Color,Color>` requires `Color` argument - `apply(Color)`

**EDIT**

Following example shows difference between **instance** and **static** *Method reference*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyColor c = new MyColor();
    Function<Color, Color> brighterInstance = c::brighterInstanceMethod; // OK
    Function<Color, Color> brighterStatic = MyColor::brighterStaticMethod; // OK

    // CASE II - trying to assign instance method via static context
    Function<Color, Color> brighter = MyColor::brighterInstanceMethod; // compilation error
}

static class MyColor {
    public Color brighterInstanceMethod(Color color) {return null;}
    public static Color brighterStaticMethod(Color color) {return null;}
}
```

So why it is legal to assign **instance no-arg** method `Color#brighter()` to `Function<Color,Color>`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // CASE I
    Function<Color, Color> brighter = Color::brighter; // surprisingly no error
    System.out.println(brighter.apply(Color.GREEN));
}
```

Since there is no error, it must somehow call referenced method `Color#brighter()` upon the object passed in to given function i. e. `Color.GREEN`.

**EDIT**

There are **two types** of **instance** [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (didn't know):

- *Reference to an instance method of a particular object*
- *Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a
  particular type*

The first one behaves like expected. Here is the describtion of the second one:

> For a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object, the type
>   to which the method belongs precedes the delimiter, and the
>   invocation's receiver is the first parameter of the functional
>   interface method:
>
> `Function<String, String> upperfier = String::toUpperCase;`
>
> Here, the implicit lambda expression has one parameter, the string to
>   be converted to upper case, which becomes the receiver of the
>   invocation of the toUpperCase() method.

For more details see [State of the lambda - 8. Method references](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html), 
[Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type)

**Sumarization**

Method reference of this type is translated as **"invoke referenced method upon function's argument"**.

**EDIT**

[Method reference to Function translation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32283953/4413257)

```
Function<Color, Color> brighter = Color::brighter; // c -> c.brighter(c);
```

**Links to similar posts**:

[Method reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754335/reference-to-methods-with-different-parameters-in-java8)

Comment: but in case I i didn't receive any complain.

Comment: please check, i have updated the question, it was my bad

Comment: exactly you got my point. which is not following the definition of Function<T,R>.

Comment: @subhashkumarsingh I wil try to find an answer for this

Comment: "_But the real question is_" - so what's the answer? It's not considered good practice an ask questions in your answers. For an answer to this question, see my answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it was just a temporary solution to point out where is the real problem, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @subhashkumarsingh take a look at my updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: There are **four** types of method references.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, but I was talking about **references to an instance method** (see links)