# Idiomatic ways to create a Stream from Nullable object?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, nullable

What are *idiomatic* ways of performing a *null-check* before generating a stream?

I have a method that receives a `List` that might be `null`. So I can't just call `stream()` on the value that is passed. Is there some static helper in that would give me an empty stream if a value is null?

Comment: I heavily suggest to work on the list providing side. The whole purpose of optionals is to not deal with `null` references. If a method returns a list that could be `null`, it should return an optional instead. If that's not possible, you can wrap it into an optional (according to the answers). Additional, you want to do something with that list, i.e. you want to _consume_ it if it is present. So simply call [`Optional.ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) on it.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I agree with [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) that `list == null ? Stream.empty() : list.stream()` is the right way to do this (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422908/464306)), or at least the right way to do this pre-Java 9 (see edit below), but I'll leave this answer up to demonstrate usage of the Optional API.

```
<T> Stream<T> getStream(List<T> list) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(list).map(List::stream).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```

---

*Edit:* Java 9 added the static factory method [`Stream.<T>ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable-T-), which returns the empty stream given a `null` argument, otherwise a stream with the argument as its only element. If the argument is a collection, we can then [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to turn it into a stream.

```
<T> Stream<T> fromNullableCollection(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
    return Stream.ofNullable(collection).flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

This doesn't misuse the Optional API as discussed by Stuart Marks, and in contrast to the ternary operator solution, there's no opportunity for a null pointer exception (like if you weren't paying attention and screwed up the order of the operands). It also works with an upper-bounded wildcard without needing `SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` thanks to the signature of `flatMap`, so you can get a `Stream<T>` from a collection of elements of any subtype of `T`.

Comment: I like this example of a helper I could reuse a bunch and avoid having `Optional.orNullable` littered throughout my code.

Comment: There is no need for the explicit type parameter `<T>` in `List::stream`; it works without. And `.orElse(Stream.empty())` may be replaced by `.orElseGet(Stream::empty)` which is slightly more efficient as it avoids constructing an empty stream.

Comment: @Holger, I made those changes, but I'm wondering what `Stream::empty` actually produces behind the scenes. An anonymous class?

Comment: See [“How will Java lambda functions be compiled?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16827262/2711488) and [“Does a lambda expression create an object on the heap every time it's executed?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27524445/2711488). Practically, there will be an instance of an anonymous class but it will be the same instance in every execution of the code (while `Stream.empty()` returns a new instance each time).

Answer (score 30):

The best thing I can think of would be to use an `Optional` with the `orElseGet` method.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(userList)
                .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                .stream()
                .map(user -> user.getName())
                .collect(toList());
```

*Updated* with @Misha's suggest to use `Collections::emptyList` over `ArrayList::new`

Comment: It's better to use `Collections::emptyList` instead of `ArrayList::new`.  It makes the intent more clear and it's (slightly) more efficient.

Comment: We can now use .orElseGet(List.of()) from Java 9 onwards

Answer (score 18):

In the other answers, the `Optional` instance is created and used strictly within the same statement. The `Optional` class is primarily useful for [communicating with the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/1441122) about presence or absence of a return value, fused with the actual value if present. Using it wholly within a single method seems unnecessary.

Let me propose the following more prosaic technique:

```
static <T> Stream<T> nullableListToStream(List<T> list) {
    return list == null ? Stream.empty() : list.stream();
}
```

I guess the ternary operator is somewhat déclassé these days, but I think this is the simplest and most efficient of the solutions.

If I were writing this for real (that is, for a real library, not just sample code on Stack Overflow) I'd put in wildcards so that that the stream return type can vary from the List type. Oh, and it can be a Collection, since that's where the `stream()` method is defined:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Stream<T> nullableCollectionToStream(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    return coll == null ? Stream.empty() : (Stream<T>)coll.stream();
}
```

(The warning suppression is necessary because of the cast from `Stream<? extends T>` to `Stream<T>` which is safe, but the compiler doesn't know that.)

Answer (score 13):

apache commons-collections4:

```
CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(list).stream()
```

Comment: Hi piotrek; your code might be correct, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: not sure what should be explained. apache commons-collections is one of the most standard java libraries. how it solves OP problem? it directly does what OP needs - it makes a stream from a nullable list

Answer (score 12):

**Java 8:**

```
Optional.ofNullable(list)
   .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
   .stream()
```

**Java 9:**

```
Stream.ofNullable(collection)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

**Apache Commons Collections 4:**

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(collection)
    .stream()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 16

Here's an option of generation a Stream from *nullable source* using Java 16 [`Stream.mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

This operation expects an argument of type `BiConsumer`, i.e. a consumer, which in turn takes *two arguments*: a **stream element** and a **consumer** of the resulting type. Each value offered to the consumer becomes a new stream element, replacing the initial element.

```
public <T> Stream<T> getStream(Collection<? extends T> c) {

    return Stream.ofNullable(c).mapMulti(Iterable::forEach);
}
```

Where the *method reference* `Iterable::forEach` representing the `BiConsumer` is an equivalent of the following lambda expression (explicit types provided for descriptiveness):

```
(Collection<? extends T> coll, Consumer<T> consumer) -> coll.forEach(consumer)
```

As well as `flatMap()` operation, `mapMulti()` is meant to perform ***one-to-many** transformations* replacing the consumed original stream element with **`0+`** (*zero or more*) elements.

**Note** that `mapMulti()` would perform better than `flatMap()` if you need to flatten a significant number of lists which contain only a few elements or can be empty. Here's a quote from the [API Note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)):

> This method is **preferable** to `flatMap` in the following circumstances:
>
> - When replacing each stream element with a **small** (*possibly zero*) number of elements. Using this method **avoids the overhead** of **creating**
>   a **new** `Stream` instance for every group of result elements, as required
>   by `flatMap`.
>   ...

---

#### Note

**1.** Lists (*as well as other Collections and arrays*) are containers of data, i.e. when you need something from a list you're interested the actual values are stored inside. A nullable container of data forces you to be right defensive unrelated to your business-logic and you or colleague might forget about that (which creates a problem which might surface at any moment).

Regardless of the source of nullable Collections, if you have a possibility to change the code you're working with, you can eliminate the actual problem, instead of hiding it using `Stream.ofNullable()` or abusing `Optional`.

These are possible sources of nullable Collections and treatments for them:

- A nullable Collection comes from a Custom object wrapped around it. Assign the field with an *empty Collection* by default.
- The data was received, for instance, as a JSON payload, and a property representing the Collection is missing or null. That basically the previous case in disguise. Examine the functionality of your parsing tool, most likely you would find a way to assign default values for properties that are absent a come as null.
- If you have a method returning a nullable Collection, then add a single condition before returning a value instead of having *null-checks* and *null-friendly* moves sprinkled all over the code. Refer to the classic book *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch, Item: "Return empty collections or arrays, not nulls".

**2.** If you need a quick way to make the code working, but you want to be aware if the incoming list `null`, then add the conditional statement to reflect the event in the logs:

```
if (list != null) logger.log( ... );
```

**3.** Lastly, as *@Stuart Marks* has pointed out in [*his answer to this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422908/17949945) `Optional` wasn't designed for *performing/hiding* null-checks. And here's a few more references regarding this topic:

- [Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945)
- [Valid usage of Optional type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945)
- [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/17949945)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I consider null deprecated and use Optional wherever possible despite the (tiny) performance overhead. So I use the interface from Stuart Marks with an implementation based on gdejohn, i.e.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Stream<T> nullableCollectionToStream(Collection<? extends T> coll)
{
    return (Stream<T>) Optional.ofNullable(coll)
                           .map(Collection::stream)
                           .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```