# Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, null, option-type

Which null-check is preferable?

```
Optional.ofNullable(port).ifPresent(settings::setPort);
```

or

```
if (port != null) {
   settings.setPort(port);
}
```

Comment: Preferable for whom? This is an opinion based question. Which one creates more overhead, for the computer and the mind of the next person to read the code?

Comment: This is opinion-based. But I prefer the second option. More readable. Additional, `Optional` has another purpose.

Comment: Just for an `if`, I would not, at least for a use of `orElse`, this become a bit more interesting.

Comment: @Kayaman that’s not so unusual. Especially as some of these points may interact.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Java, an `Optional` value is a fusion of a bit that indicates presence or absence, with a value of an arbitrary reference type `T` or a primitive `int`, `long`, or `double`.

Fusing these is especially useful when returning a value from a method, as methods have only a single return value. It's often necessary to use a special value such as `null` in the case of reference types, or -1 in the case of `int`, as a sentinel to indicate the "no-value" case. Using `Optional` as a return value avoids the problem of the caller accidentally misusing the sentinel value as the real return value.

Given this, line of code such as

```
Optional.ofNullable(port).ifPresent(settings::setPort);
```

is strange in that it fuses a value with the present/absent bit in the first part of the line and then immediately separates them in the second part of the line. This adds complexity to what is ultimately a fairly simple task: checking whether `port` is non-null and conditionally performing some action. The alternative code snippet:

```
if (port != null) {
    settings.setPort(port);
}
```

expresses quite clearly exactly what it does.

It's true that the if-statement takes more vertical space than the `Optional` chain. The `Optional` chain is denser, but it's also harder to understand: a poor tradeoff.

Comment: This is the only correct answer given here. It deserves more +1s. Java8 in action promotes `Optional.ofNullable(port).ifPresent(settings::setPort);` kind of use of `Optional`. But `Optional` have severe performance issues according to some books. So it should only be used as a return value from a function.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I totally disagree with this - we use this pattern in our code, not much, but we do. The thing is, is that for *our* team - apparently this is a lot easier to read (myself included).

Comment: Optional is syntactic sugar and comes at its own cost. for simple null checks, better use traditional null checks

Comment: one more point here is additional objects created (though minor) when there is no real need for it. 1+

Comment: People today underestimate the cost of object creation and function calling. Refactoring simple looking Optional chains to traditional style gives me between 300 % to 1500 % performance boost. Which is also relevant in non-performant-critical apps, say if the app is scaled e.g.

Answer (score 7):

Although, the snippet you have posted in the question is just a simple way to avoid the ugly `null-check`, yet is valid, correct and null-safe. Follow your personal preference in this case.

The real power of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) are the following methods:

- [`Optional::filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) which applies a filter on a *present* value.
- [`Optional::map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) which applies a mapping function on a *present* value.

As example, let's say you want to get another value from `port` to add to the list and avoid the NPE if `port` is `null`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(port).map(port::getSomeValue).ifPresent(settings::setPort);
```

Moreover, please, avoid the following meaningless substitution of `null-check` I see often:

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(port).isPresent()) {
    settings.setPort(port);
}
```

Comment: `.map(Port::getSomeValue)` to keep it simple. You really see the last point often ? That's sad !

Comment: What is ugly about a null check?

Comment: @HannesSchneidermayer It is verbose and often unnecessary if the developers strictly follow the contracts (`@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` annotations are also helpful). Moreover, Kotlin handles it easily with Elvis operator or nullable (`?`) types.

Comment: It is not really verbose, it is fundamental to programming. I agree with the annotations being helpful. Elvis is also just a null check disguised as syntax sugar (better readable for sure, but still the same thing). So a regular null-check for a nullable is nothing ugly in my opinion, it's been there forever and it is the most normal thing in programming. No reason to create a Optional object or call functions. But you mentioned the same in your answer, so I think we probably agree on most of this.

Comment: It is verbose: a null check to be readable requires 3 lines, otherwise one uses a single one, period. If developers both define and follow contracts strictly, we would be able to get rid of most of the null-checks. Most of them are unnecessary and caused only by insufficient contracts and communication between the teams.

Answer (score 2):

It is dependent on several factors when to use this. 
If `port` is a property within the class, probably using `Optional` is a bit overkill. (and don't use`Optional`s as property as they are [not serializbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc))

I think `Optional`s are great when for example writing a library.

```
public Optional<Integer> getPort()
```

Is much more descriptive for other developers then

```
// Returns null if not set
public Integer getPort()
```

Comment: Returning `null` is usually implied, so that wouldn't really warrant a comment nor would it be surprising to get `null` back. `Optional` has its places, but it's not an automatic replacement for methods that may return `null`.

Comment: @Kayaman Maybe my example is oversimplified also because of "simple" get method. Like anything else use it where it makes sense. But there might be methods where it is not so implied, or parameters to make it more clear.

Comment: Indeed, but like this question shows, some people think `Optional` was a replacement for `null`, which it isn't. Kind of like sopme people think streams are a replacement for normal loops, and you have questions for "improving" code by replacing loops with streams.