# How to replace my old Java code with Optionals (Functional programming)?

Tags: java, functional-interface

How to replace the below code using Java 8 Optionals (Functional programming)?

```
ClassA classA = dbService.findByA(a);

if (classA == null) {
    classA = dbService.findByB(b);
}

if (classA == null) {
    throw new Exception();
}

return classA;
```

edit:
Maybe if I will make `findByA` and `findByB` returning Optional will make my code cleaner using Functional programming?

Comment: A functional interface is an interface that contains only one abstract method. What exactly do you need to implement using the functional interface?

Comment: I think you want a solution using the functional programming paradigm.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was unclear. I want to make it with Optionals (Functional programming).

Comment: Make findByA return an Optional<ClassA>. If you can't do that, then don't touch anything in that code. Optional is not meant to replace null checks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038417/should-optional-ofnullable-be-used-for-null-check

Comment: throwing an exception is not a functional style/programing

Answer (score 3):

```
return Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(dbService.findByA(a))
    .orElseGet(() -> dbService.findByB(b)))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
```

Or, Java 9, a bit nicer:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dbService.findByA(a))
    .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(dbService.findByB(b)))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
```

Comment: `.or(() -> dbService.findByB(b))` doesn't work since `dbService.findByB(b)` doesn't return an `Optional`.

Answer (score 2):

This would work

```
Optional.ofNullable(
    Optional.ofNullable(dbService.findByA(a))
            .orElseGet(() -> dbService.findByB(b))
).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

I don't think this is much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your methods `dbService.findByA` and `dbService.findByB` return `Optional`. That's the basis. If you don't do that, you don't do "functional" programming.

Second, use Java 9+ (or better, the latest version).

Then simply use the following:

```
ClassA instance = dbService.findByA(a)
    .or(() -> dbService.findByB(b))
    .orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

If you're stuck with Java 8, do the following:

```
ClassA instance = Optional.of(() -> dbService.findByA(a)) // Optional<Optional<ClassA>>
    .orElseGet(() -> dbService.findByB(b)) // Optional<ClassA>
    .orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

Comment: I can make them returning Optional but I can't use Java 9+, can you help me how to write it in Java 8?

Comment: @0seNse0 I updated my answer. It's ugly and similar to the other answers. That's why I strongly recommend upgrading to Java 9 or higher. Java 8 is already 5.5 years old (and is not commercially supported anymore). That's a lot! You should really have a plan for upgrade.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Java 9/10 can't be download, only Java 11, and Java 8 is supported https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html

Comment: @user7294900 My bad. I based myself on the Wikipedia article which apparently isn't up to date on that regards. Anyways, it's good to keep up with the ongoing developments and use later versions to not be left behind when Java 8 isn't supported anymore.