# Java Streams; avoid finisher on Collectors.collectingAndThen

Tags: java, java-stream

I've this code:

```java
private Iterable<Practitioner> pickPractitioners(List<String> ids) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(ids)
        .map(List::stream)
        .orElse(Stream.of())
        .collect(
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                this.practitionerRepository::findAllById
            )
        );

}
```

Problem is that when `ids` is empty, `this.practitionerRepository::findAllById` is also executed.

I'd like to avoid this step if resulting collector is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have control over the practitionerRepository yourself, a solution could be to simply accept an empty list (returning an empty iterable) - something like `practitionerRepository.findAllById(Stream.ofNullable(ids).flatMap(List::stream).toList())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst the practical part of this question (`how to avoid interrogating the repository with an empty list as an argument`) is already addressed in other answers I want to point out that there's a cleaner way to build a pipeline in this method.

Firstly it's worthy to remind that the main purpose of `Optional.ofNullable()` is to create an Optional object that has to be **`returned from a method`**.

Attempts to use `Optional.ofNullable()` in order to utilize method-chaining or to avoid null-checks in the middle of the method according to [**Stuart Marks**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) are considered to be anti-patterns.

Here is the quote from his [**talk at Devoxx**](https://youtu.be/fBYhtvY19xA?t=1445):

> "it's generally a bad idea to create an Optional for the specific
> purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value."

A similar idea was expressed in his [`answer on stackoverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945).

**What are the alternatives?**

Since Java 9 **`Stream interface`** has its own method [**`ofNullable()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)).

> Returns a sequential Stream containing a single element, if non-null,
> otherwise returns an empty Stream.

Keeping all that in mind method `pickPractitioners()` could be rewritten like this:

```
private Function<List<String>, Iterable<Practitioner>> getPractitioners =
        idList -> idList.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : 
                                     this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(idList);


private Iterable<Practitioner> pickPractitioners(List<String> ids) {

    return Stream.ofNullable(ids)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toList(),
                            getPractitioners
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In general to skip that part of the finisher you could pass a lambda instead of a method reference and check if the input is empty:

```
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            r -> r.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(r)
        )
    );
```

If your actual code is a simple as this example then you don't need to use streams or optional at all. Instead you could just check if the input of the method is null or empty in a ternary operator:

```
    return ids == null || ids.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() :
        this.practitionerRepository.findAllById(ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the signature of the Finisher.  It is just a function, so you can just write it:

> ```
> public static<T,A,R,RR> Collector<T,A,RR> collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream, Function<R,RR> finisher) {
> ```

```
static interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Part, Long> {

}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyRepository myRepository = null;
    List<Long> list = null;

    Function<List<Long>, List<Part>> finisher = (ids) -> {

        return ids.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : myRepository.findAllById(ids);

    };

    Optional.ofNullable(list)
            .map(List::stream)
            .orElse(Stream.of())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toList(),
                            finisher
                    )
            );

}
```