# What is the difference between Optional.ofNullable() and `Optional.of()

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, nullable, null-check

First of all, I know the difference between the two methods.

- `Optional.of` : Used to ensure that there is no null, if null is entered, nullPointExcepction
- `Optional.ofNullable` : may or may not be null. Used to respond flexibly.

So, if I add `orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("null data"))` to this, will it end up being the same?

I want to throw an error with explicit content.

So I get `Optional.ofNullable(data).orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("null data")))`

use it as Is this pointless behaviour?

`Optional.of(data).orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("null data")))`

I think this is also possible, but I'm just using `ofNullable()` to make the code look consistent.

to sum it up,
In the end, if you add `orElseThrow(nullPoint)`
Are `of` or `ofNullable` the same result?

then rather
Is `of.orElseThrow` better?

Comment: There's a third way to get an NPE: `orElseThrow(null)`

Comment: Beyond simply getting the npe, I want to send a message to the npe. (The process of printing this is prepared.)

In the end I have no choice but to use orElseThrow(() ->  new NullPointerException("message")) to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, if you want to customize the exception, you should use `orElseThrow`.

Comment: That is if you're doing something else in the Optional chain. Calling it immediately after initializing the Optional would be weird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> to sum it up, In the end, if you add orElseThrow(nullPoint) Are of or ofNullable the same result?

No. To see this, simply look at the types.

> ```
> public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value);
>
> public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
>                                throws X extends Throwable;
> ```

`Optional.of` returns an `Optional<T>`, where `orElseThrow` is going to leave you with a `T`. So `Optional.ofNullable(x).orElseThrow(...)` is really just a very roundabout

```
if (x == null) {
  throw new NullPointerException(...);
}
```

You're not actually *doing* anything with the `Optional`, just making one and discarding it in a really verbose way. So if that's your intent, just do an explicit `null` check; there's no need at all for `Optional`.

Which raises the question of why we would use `of` or `ofNullable`. With the introduction of `Optional`, there are now two ways to represent the concept of "this value might not exist" in Java: `null` and `Optional.empty()`. People on the Internet will argue till the end of time about which is better and when you should use which one (I have strong opinions on this which I'll refrain from sharing here, since it's not what you asked), but the point is that there are two different ways to do it.

For the rest of this post, I'll borrow a bit of notation from Kotlin and write `T?` to mean "a `T` value which might be `null`". It's not valid Java notation, but it gets the point across. So if we want to represent "A `T` which may or may not exist" in Java, we can use either `Optional<T>` or `T?`.

If we want to go from `T?` to `Optional<T>`, that's what `Optional.ofNullable` is for. It says "If the thing is `null`, give me `Optional.empty()`; otherwise give me the thing in an `Optional`". To go the other way, we can use `Optional.orElse(null)`, which says "If I have a `T`, give it to me, otherwise show me `null`". So now we have a way to convert between the two approaches. So what's `Optional.of` for?

You should view `Optional.of` as an assertion of sorts. If Java had nullable types like Kotlin, then the difference would be something like

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value);
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T? value);
```

That is, `ofNullable` expects that its value might be `null`. `of` is already assuming that it's not. `Optional.of` should be thought of an assertion that the value you're giving it is not null. If that assertion fails, we throw `NullPointerException` immediately rather than letting errors propagate to other parts of the program. If you're calling `Optional.of` and recovering from the `NullPointerException` it throws<sup>[1]</sup>, then you are doing something *very wrong*. That function is an assertion we were dealing with non-null data to begin with, and if that assertion fails then your program should fail immediately with a good stack trace.

It sounds like, based on your use case, you have a value that might be `null`. In that case, `Optional.ofNullable` makes sense; it's prepared to handle the use case. If you want to throw a custom exception, you should do a null check beforehand (since *you're* the one handling the `null`, not `Optional`) and then call `Optional.of`. Or, of course, you can just do an old-fashioned `null` check and not use `Optional` at all, if you're planning to extract it anyway with `orElseThrow`. Certainly, the pipeline `Optional.ofNullable(value).orElseThrow(...)` in one line would be a code smell.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Note that I say "recovering from", not "catching". A nice top-level `catch (Exception exc)` which logs all errors is perfectly acceptable and generally a good idea in larger applications. But if you're doing `catch (NullPointerException exc) { return 0; }` or something like that then you need to reconsider which `Optional` method you should be using.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply.

After learning Optional, I mainly used it for validation.

There must be a value, but in case it doesn't exist for some reason (malicious attack).

Thanks to your answer, I thought my code was bad code. Is your intention correct?

Comment: A little more about my situation,
There are values ​​a, b, and c, a and b must have a value, and c doesn't matter.

At this time, I
Optional.ofNullable (a).orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException(" a = null data")))

Optional.ofNullable (b).orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("b = null data")))

I use it like this:
Is it very wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you don't really need `Optional` at all. I would go with old-fashioned `if (a == null)` checks and throw exceptions explicitly. You're getting none of the benefits of `Optional` the way you're doing it and you're really just obfuscating the core point of the code, which is validation and a custom error.

Comment: After listening to you and checking again, I realized what mistake I had made. Thank you.

I'm sorry to bother you with the continued question, but maybe Optional.of / Optional.ofNullable
Can you point me to a situation or example of this meaningful use?

Comment: `Optional.of` is basically the constructor for `Optional`, so you use that when you want to *construct* an `Optional` out a value you already trust to be non-`null`. `Optional.ofNullable` is for converting potentially null values to `Optional` ones, for instance if you're coming from a library that uses `null` and you'd prefer to use `Optional` or vice versa.

Comment: I also think the if(a==null) method you mentioned is valid.

However, I learned that the purpose of Optional is mostly to check for null.

However, when used, it can actually reduce readability.

I don't know how to use it correctly...

Comment: “If Java had nullable types” we would probably not need `Optional` at all. By the way, the idiomatic alternative to `if (x == null) { throw new NullPointerException(message); }` is [`Objects.requireNonNull(x, message);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, I know the difference between the two methods.
>
> `Optional.of` : Used to ensure that there is no `null`, if `null` is
> entered, nullPointExcepction
>
> `Optional.ofNullable` : may or may not be `null`. Used to respond
> flexibly.

There's a clear point of misunderstanding.

The purpose of `Optional.of()` is not *"to ensure that there is no `null`"*. It is not meant to be used as an assertion that a value that was passed into it is *non-null*. For such a validation you can use [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), it'll either throw an **NPE**, or will return you a *non-null value*.

In order to be on the same page, the first important thing you have to keep in mind is that *optionals* were introduced in the JDK for only *one particular purpose* - to serve as a ***return type***. Any other cases when *optional* is utilized as a parameter-type, or a field-type, or when optional objects are being stored in a collection isn't considered to be a good practice. As well, as creating an *optional* just in order to chain methods on it or to hide a null-check is considered to be an ***antipattern***.

Here is [a couple of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945) from the answer by *@StuartMarks*, developer of the JDK:

> The **primary use** of Optional is as follows:
>
> Optional is intended to
> provide a limited mechanism for library **method return types** where
> there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null
> for that is overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.

> A typical **code smell** is, instead of the code using method chaining to
> handle an Optional returned from some method, it **creates an Optional**
> from something that's nullable, **in order to chain methods** and **avoid
> conditionals**.

I also suggest you to have a look at this answer to the question [*"Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945), also by *Stuart Marks*.

With all that being said, combination `Optional.of().orElseThrow()` is both wrong and pointless:

- If provided data is `null` method `of()` will raise an **NPE** and `orElseThrow()` will not be executed (*i.e. its exception will get never be fired*).
- You're abusing the *optional* by creating an optional object not in order to return a *nullable variable* wrapped by it, but to hide the null-check (*take a look at the quote above*). That obscures the purpose of your code. You can use `Objects.requireNonNull()` instead to throw an exception if the given value must not be `null` or `requireNonNullElse()` to provide a default value.

For the same reason, you shouldn't use `Optional.ofNullable().orElseThrow()` at the first place.

#### Optional is like a Box

You might think of *optional* is if it is a *parcel*. When you need to send something, you go to the post office (*i.e. **returning** from the method*), where the thing that has to be sent is being placed into a *box*. When somebody (*i.e. the **caller***) receives the *parcel*, it is being immediately unpacked. That is the whole lifecycle of the box called `Optional`.

When, according to the logic of your application, an object required to be returned from the method should not be `null` - use `Optional.of()`. It'll either send a parcel successfully or will emphasize that there's a problem by raising a `NullPointerException`.

If the given object is *nullable* by its nature, i.e. `null` isn't an abnormal case, then use `Optional.ofNullable()`, it'll fire either a box containing the object or an empty box.

And the **caller** (*i.e. method that invokes the method returning an optional*) is the one who has to unpack the *box* using a variety of tools that *optional* provides like `orElseThrow()`, `orElseGet()`, `ifPresent()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks to you, I know how to use it correctly. Thank you.

However, it was a bit difficult, so I didn't fully understand it.
I know when not to use it, but I don't know when it's good to use it.

If you don't mind, can you give me a simple example?

Comment: @바보린 Ok. Firstly, as a rule of thumb, don't stick the `Optional` in the middle of your methods. Let's assume have a method that processes the input somehow and using the resulting data it makes a call (to a library, to a legacy part of your system, a database query, important thing is that the value returned by that call can be `null`). And you must return that value at all cost, i.e. even if it is `null` (an indicator that request failed). So instead of returning `null` you can wrap it with an optional object by making of `Optional.ofNullable()`.

Comment: And when you have a method that returns `Optional` with several conditional statements, and there's a case when you are *certain* that the produced value is *non-null*, then you should use `Optional.of()`. Because it'll will be obvious to the reader of your code that this value isn't expected to be `null`, if you would utilize `ofNullable()` instead it might create confusion. That's how you can distinguish between them.

Comment: Also, remember a *simple rule*: every time you're returning `null`, stop and try to think of other option. Which are to use an `Optional`, to throw an exception right on the spot, or implement the *null-object pattern* (depending on your needs).

Comment: You've been very helpful, but I'm late to thank you.

Thanks to your additional explanation, I just opened my eyes!