# Retrieve stream from Optional<Stream>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

How can I get the actual stream in order to filter or map methods from an Optional ?
For instance

```
Optional.ofNullable(id)
        .map(this:loadAllById) // method loadAllById return a stream (now is wrapped in Optional<Stream>)
        .filter(obj -> obj.status) // here i have no access to object in stream but to the full stream
```

From this a doubt also arises. Is it correct to have a stream inside an Optional? Since the stream should always be not null (in case empty) shouldn't the check be needed?

Comment: Yeah, you're mixing two APIs: Optional and Stream. Try `.map(this:loadAllById).orElseGet(Stream::empty).filter(...)`: `filter` will now be Stream's, not Optional's.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that container elements like collections or streams are better off represented as empty elements, instead of wrapped in an `Optional`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, you don't need to use `Optinal` at all.

Optional was **not** designed to perform `null`-checks and `Optional.ofNullable(id)` is an abuse of optional (*see [Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945)*). Use an explicit null-check instead.

An **empty stream** can represent the absence of data, you don't need an empty optional for that. Make your method `loadAllById()` return a stream `Stream<Foo>` instead of optional of stream `Optional<Stream<Foo>>`. Wrapping a stream with an optional isn't a proper usage of optional (*as it has been already  mentioned in the comments by @MC Emperor*).

That's how your code might look like:

```
public Stream<Foo> getFoosById(Long id, Status status) {
    if (id == null) {
        return Stream.empty();
    }
    
    return loadAllById(id).filter(foo -> foo.getStatus().equals(status));
}
```

If `status` is an *enum* you can check reference equality with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Optional.ofNullable(id)
        .stream()       // Java 9
        .flatMap(this::loadAllById)
        .filter(...)
```