# How to Implement Functional If-Then-Else in Java

Tags: java, option-type, java-11, flatmap, functional-java

Given the following `Function` implementations...

**Get User Credentials From Master Database**

```
private Function<Long, Optional<UserCredentials>>
    getUserCredentialsFromMaster() {
        return userId -> Optional.ofNullable(userId)
            .flatMap(masterUserRepository::findById)
            .map(User::getCredentials);
}
```

**Get User Credentials From Secondary Database**

```
private Function<Long, Optional<UserCredentials>>
    getUserCredentialsFromSecondary() {
        return userId -> Optional.ofNullable(userId)
            .flatMap(secondaryUserRepository::findById)
            .map(User::getCredentials);
}
```

I need to execute **either** `getUserCredentialsFromMaster` or `getUserCredentialsFromSecondary` depending on where `userId` comes from.

*Here below is my attempt:*

Consider domain class `UserProfile`

```
public class UserProfile {
    Long id;
    Long internalUserId; // if internalUserId is null then externalUserId is not
    Long externalUserId; // and vice-versa
}
```

Attempt to obtain `UserCredentials`:

```
final UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findById(userProvileId);

final UserCredentials userCredentials =
    Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.internalUserId)
        .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromMaster())
        .orElse(
            Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.externalUserId)
                .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromSecondary())
                .orElseThrow(UserCredentialsNotFound::new));
```

`internalUserId` is not `null` but the statements above always throw `UserCredentialsNotFound`. I've tried to rewrite `getUserCredentialsFromMaster` and `getUserCredentialsFromSecondary` as plain Java methods invoked from an *if-then-else* block, and it worked as expected.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Both `getImplementationStrategyByModelPortfolioId()` and `getImplementationStrategyByMandateId()` are parameterless, i.e. they don't depend on `internalUserId` and `externalUserId` (you just need them to be non-null) or it's an unintentional mistake?

Comment: ...  `getImplementationStrategyByModelPortfolioId()` and `getImplementationStrategyByMandateId()` were just copy-past from my actual code. In the example code they should have been `getUserCredentialsFromMaster()` and `getUserCredentialsFromSecondary()`, respectively. Sorry

Comment: By the way, either `internalUserId` or `externalUserId` must have an actual value.

Comment: One more clarification, your repository `masterUserRepository::findById` returns an `Optional<User>` or a nullable `User` instance?

Comment: It returns `Optional<User>`... but I could rework it to return a nullable object. It doesn't matter for me :-)

Comment: I was asking because in the first functions it should be `.flatMap(secondaryUserRepository::findById)` if repository returns `Optional<User>`. And there's a mismatch in the type of parameters consumed by Functions (`Long` vs `String` in the `UserProfile`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You're getting an exception because the argument of the `Optional.orElse()` is evaluated eagerly. I.e. it would be evaluated even if the `Optional` on which it was invoked is not empty.

But as you have said, either *"`internalUserId` is `null` then `externalUserId` is not `null` and vice-versa"* and `orElseThrow()` produces an exception.

## Avoid using Optional to replace Null-checks

Firstly, note that `Optional` wasn't designed to perform null-checks. The design goal of the `Optional` is to serve as a **return type**, and its method `ofNullable()` is supposed to wrap a nullable return value, not to substitute a *null-check*.

You might be interested in reading:

- [Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945)
- [Valid usage of Optional type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945)

And there's nothing wrong with implicit null-checks, it's a bit of a problem when there are a lot of them in the code, but it's rather an immediate consequence of how particular behavior in the application was implemented, then the issue related to the tools offered by the language.

The cleaner way to address this problem would be to get read of the functions and define a method producing a `Supplier` based on the provided `id` and `UserRepository`:

```
private Supplier<Optional<UserCredentials>> getUserCredentials(Long id, UserRepository repository) {
    
    return id == null ?
        Optional::empty :
        () -> repository.findById(id).map(User::getCredentials);
}
```

Which can be used in the following way:

```
UserCredentials userCredentials = Stream.of(
        getUserCredentials(userProfile.internalUserId, masterUserRepository),
        getUserCredentials(userProfile.internalUserId, secondaryUserRepository)
    )
    .map(Supplier::get)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(UserCredentialsNotFound::new);
```

## If you still want to keep using Optional

As a remedy you can use Java 9 [`Optional.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) which expects a `Supplier` of `Optional` which would be evaluated only if needed.

```
UserCredentials userCredentials = Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.internalUserId)
    .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromMaster())
    .or(() ->
        Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.externalUserId)
            .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromSecondary())
    )
    .orElseThrow(UserCredentialsNotFound::new);
```

Alternatively, you can make use [`Optional.orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) which takes a `Supplier` of resulting value:

```
UserCredentials userCredentials = Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.internalUserId)
    .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromMaster())
    .orElseGet(() ->
        Optional.ofNullable(userProfile.externalUserId)
            .flatMap(getUserCredentialsFromSecondary())
            .orElseThrow(UserCredentialsNotFound::new)
    );
```

Comment: This was also a solution I tried and it worked... but I'm wondering whether I could get rid of the lambda.

Comment: @j3d When you're writing something like `foo(bar)`, argument `bar` should be evaluated before in order to invoke `foo()`. When instead of `bar` you have `foo(baz())` then method `baz()` should be executed prior to the invocation of `foo()`. Hence in your case you have a choice between replacing `orElseThrow()` with `orElse(defaultValue)`, or if you need to throw then - you need to use a Function via `or()`, or `orElseGet()`.