# Optional - Unhandled exception using orElseThrow()

Tags: java, exception, option-type

I want to throw a custom exception in case parsing fails, but the compiler complains that there is an unhandled `ParserException` that comes from the `parse()` method.

But What am I missing?

*My code:*

```
public void validateConstraints(RequestType body) {
    
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatYearMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    
    Date date = Optional
        .ofNullable(body.date())
        .map(simpleDateFormatYearMonth::parse)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidCustomException(""));
}
```

Comment: `orElseThrow` is used to throw an exception only if the `Optional` is empty - it will not *catch*  or react on the `ParseException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

- Your apparent issue stems from the fact `java.util.Function` as well as many other functional interfaces doesn't declare to throw any checked Exceptions in its abstract method. For that reason, implementations can't violate the contract providing behavior which is less safe than declared.

Here's a quote from the [Java Language Specification `§8.4.8.3.` **Requirements in Overriding and Hiding**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> For every checked exception type listed in the `throws` clause of `m2`, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure (§4.6) of the `throws` clause of `m1`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

With that being said, you can't propagate a checked exception outside the lambda or method reference (*since it's not declared, it should be handled right on the spot*).

- Creating an `Optional` only for the purpose of hiding null-check, and chaining methods on it is a misuse of `Optional` since it goes against its design goal.
- `java.util.Date` (and `java.sql.Date`) as well as `SimpleDateFormat` are obsolete since Java 8 (*reminder: this version was released more than 10 years ago*). As a replacement we have a new Time API, represented by classes that reside in `java.time` package, like `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter`, etc.

## Avoid using Optional to replace Null-checks

The design goal of the `Optional` is to serve as a **return type**, and its method `ofNullable()` is supposed to wrap a nullable return value, not to perform validation.

You might be interested in reading:

- [Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945)
- [Valid usage of Optional type in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945)

Here's a short quote from the linked above answer by *@StuartMarks*, Java and OpenJDK developer:

> A **typical code smell** is, instead of the code using method chaining to handle an Optional returned from some method, it **creates an Optional** from something that's nullable, in order **to chain methods and avoid conditionals**.

To validate if a value is not `null` JDK offers overloaded method `Objects.requireNoneNull()`, which was specifically designed for that purpose. But in this case it's not applicable because you need to throw your custom exception (`requireNoneNull()` operates via NPE, you can only provide a custom message).

The last thing worth to point out before diving into the solution, is that there's **nothing wrong** with **implicit null-checks** (*if you have quite a bit of them that's an issue, which is rooted in a way your classes and behavior are designed, rather than related to the tools offered by the language*).

Therefore, I would advise to implement this functionality using a plain conditional logic:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat YEAR_MONTH_DAY = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public void validateConstraints(RequestType body) {
    if (tryParse(body.date()) == null) throw new InvalidCustomException("message");
}

private Date tryParse(String str) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        if (str != null) date = YEAR_MONTH_DAY.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't use Optionals for control flow; limit their usage to return types only.