# How to fix Following NullPointerException Using java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, nullpointerexception, java-stream

The following code gives me a `NullPointerException`. As my examine, it is caused by `containerModels` being null.

```
 List<DoseDetailMutableDTOToBaseDoseDetailAdapter> adapters = 
     containerModels.stream()
                    .map(DoseDetailMutableDTOToBaseDoseDetailAdapter::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to fix it using java 8?

Comment: `Stream.ofNullable` might help there.

Comment: @nullpointer is it correct , put it like this, ' containerModels.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map..'

Comment: If `containerModels`, you would still get an NPE.

Comment: Try like  `Optional.ofNullable(lcontainerModels)`

Comment: @nullpointer `Stream.ofNullable` Java9 right ?

Comment: @nullpointer i am using java 8  . :(

Comment: @uma check this link this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406286/how-to-best-create-a-java-8-stream-from-a-nullable-object

Comment: @nullpointer `Optional::ofNullable`, not stream...

Comment: Just `adapters = containerModels == null? Collections.emptyList(): containerModels.stream() .map(DoseDetailMutableDTOToBaseDoseDetailAdapter::new) .collect(Collectors.toList());` or better, fix the preceding code which allowed `containerModels` to ever become `null`.

Comment: @Eugene Well when I made the comment I actually meant [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)).. but of course `Optional.ofNullable` is also an option.

Comment: @manfromnowhere yes Java-9.

Comment: @Holger I too stumble often into the fanciness of the streams/optional to perform such operations and then realize it was better done without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do the trick:

```
Optional.ofNullable(containerModels)
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .stream()
        ...
```