# Java streams optional with null check on two items

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have the following code which works on two values viz. a `List` of `String` and a `String`. Both the `List` and `String` can be `null`.

```
List<String> myStringList = getMyStringList(); // may return null
String myString = "abc"; // may be null

List<String> finalStringList = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
            .map(strings -> strings.stream()
                    .filter(obj -> StringUtils.isEmpty(myString)
                            || myString.equals(obj))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Idea is:
If `myStringList` is `null`, then result in an empty `ArrayList`.
If `myString` is `null`, then return `myStringList` as is.
If `myString` is not null, then loop through the list and return all items matching `myString`.

Problem is, with solution above, I still loop through the whole list (`strings.stream`) even when `myString` is null.

Assuming `myStringList` is very big, how can I avoid looping the list for the case when `myString` is null?

That is,

1) do a null check on the list. If null, return a new empty list.

2) do a null check on `myString`. If null, return the list as is WITHOUT LOOPING.

3) if `myString` is not null, loop through the list and return the filtered list.

Comment: why you are not using simple if check.

Comment: Best solution: fix `getMyStringList()` to return an empty list instead of `null`.

Comment: Related and a very good read: [How to best create a Java 8 stream from a nullable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406286/how-to-best-create-a-java-8-stream-from-a-nullable-object) (I suggest that this question is partially a duplicate of that one)

Comment: @Vicky The question would be really clear if you could draw the expectation with all 4 possible combinations of `myString` and `myStringList` 's presence and absence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ternary like,

```
List<String> finalStringList = myString == null ?
        Collections.emptyList()
        : Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
        .map(strings -> strings.stream()
                .filter(obj -> StringUtils.isEmpty(myString)
                        || myString.equals(obj))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Or a basic `if` and default to an empty list. Like,

```
List<String> finalStringList = Collections.emptyList();
if (myString != null) {
    finalStringList = Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
            .map(strings -> strings.stream()
                    .filter(obj -> StringUtils.isEmpty(myString)
                            || myString.equals(obj))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
}
```

Comment: So you reckon I will have to use a ternary.. I thought of that.. but wanted to be sure if that is the only way and it can not be done using Streams and Optional..

Comment: The `if` does not use a ternary; so you don't "have to use a ternary". But you can.

Comment: As this requirement says: "2) do a null check on myString. If null, return the list as is WITHOUT LOOPING." than this `Collections.emptyList()` should be rather `myStringList`

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you (with Java 9+):

```
List<String> result2 = Optional.ofNullable(myString)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(mystr -> Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .or(() -> Optional.of(new ArrayList<>()))
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .filter(mystr::equals)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())) //ArrayList not guaranteed
    .orElse(myStringList);
```

If you're using Java 8, the following should work, but it looks a little harder to read:

```
List<String> result = Optional.ofNullable(myString)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(mystr -> Optional.ofNullable(myStringList)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(list -> list.stream()
                            .filter(mystr::equals)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .orElseGet(ArrayList::new))
  .orElse(myStringList);
```

Comment: I am on Java 8. But your solution with Java 8 is not working.

Comment: It throws NullPointerException when myStringList is null.

Comment: @Vicky. No, I get an empty list when I test it. You may need to share your snippet.

Comment: added snippet in the answer

Comment: @Vicky Your requirements stated * If `myString` is null, then return `myStringList` as is*. In your example, `myString` is null, and therefore the result is null. But you're calling `System.out.println(result.size());` without checking if `result` is null. That explains your NPE. Right?

Comment: ok. my bad. I should have worded better... What I meant was, the null check for list is already done.. so we proceed only when list is not empty.. so the point where I say "as is" null check on list has already being done, and the list is not empty...

Comment: @Vicky Not too sure what you mean. In this code, if `myStringList` is null, the inner stream won't run. That's the behavior of `Optional.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution

```java
List<String> myStringList = Arrays.asList("abc", "aef"); // may return null
String myString = "abc"; // may be null

Map<Predicate, Supplier<List<String>>> predicateMap = Map.of(
      (v) -> myStringList == null, () -> new ArrayList<>(), // do a null check on the list. If null, return a new empty list.
      (v) -> myString == null, () -> myStringList, // do a null check on myString. If null, return the list as is WITHOUT LOOPING.
      (v) -> true, () -> myStringList.stream() // if myString is not null, loop through the list and return the filtered list.
                .filter(myString::equals)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
      );
List<String> outputList = predicateMap.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getKey().test(null))
      .findFirst().get().getValue().get();

System.out.println(outputList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the code by `if-else` will be much more readable/maintainable/efficient:

```
if (myStringList == null || myStringList.size() == 0) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
} else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myString)) {
    return new ArrayList<>(myStringList); // or return myStringList;
} else {
    return myStringList.stream().filter(e -> myString.equals(e))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Okay, if you really want to avoid writing a few lines of code, try my library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
return N.isNullOrEmpty(myString) ? N.newArrayList(myStringList) 
                                 : N.filter(myStringList, e -> myString.equals(e));
```