# lambda expression within method body

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method like this

```
public void doThis(){
   Predicate<String> p = (arg) -> true;
   doThat(p);
}
```

Will this have any performance impact as compared to doing it without lambda ?
Is it possible to store this lambda expression as a instance variable to make it better ?

Comment: I can't answer the first part (other than the usual: worry about performance when you have a performance problem to worry about), but re the latter, of course you can: `private Predicate<String> p = (arg) -> true;`.

Comment: Doing what without lambda? This method does effectively nothing.

Comment: The method `doThis` does not actually do anything except declaring a Predicate that remains unused. Did you want to return it ?

Comment: @Henry added more code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder will it make any difference (good/bad)if I refactor it as a instance variable.

Comment: It depends on how often you would call that method (and hence create a new predicate). Making it a static class member (no need to access instance scope) is probably faster, but also it probably does not really matter.

Comment: You could also make it  a private static Predicate or even better a complete new private static method and use it in dothis().

Comment: the only way to verify performance assumptions is to measure it ;) Everything else is as reliable as reading tea leaves ..

Answer (score 0):

you can see performance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Predicate using Lambda");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        doThis();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("Predicate using Without Lambda");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        doThisWithoutLambda();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("Predicate using Lambda 100000");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            doThis();
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

        System.out.println("Predicate using Without Lambda 100000");
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            doThisWithoutLambda();
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static void doThis() {
        Predicate<String> p = (arg) -> true;

    }

    public static void doThisWithoutLambda() {
        Predicate<String> p = new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean evaluate(String object) {
                return true;
            }
        };

    }
```

Output :

```
Predicate using Lambda
1551087600419
1551087600491
Predicate using Without Lambda
1551087600491
1551087600492
Predicate using Lambda 100000
1551087600492
1551087600496
Predicate using Without Lambda 100000
1551087600496
1551087600500
```

> [Java lambdas 20 times slower than anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585444/java-lambdas-20-times-slower-than-anonymous-classes)

Comment: Are you as confused as I am about the 100000 iterations taking _less_ time than the single evaluation of the method? (Besides that method of measurement not being super-precise, I would not be surprised if the compiler optimized the lambda/inner class away as it is never used at all.)

Comment: Lamdas is faster if you have more iterations and only solwer in a first time initialization.

Comment: You can't trust the numbers from that code. Why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java