# Java Streams .max() and .min() lag in performance?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, max, min

Consider Below 2 examples.

## 1 With Streams

```
myList.stream().map(this::getInt).max(Integer::compareTo);
```

## 2 Old way

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (MyItem item : myList) {
    max = Math.max(max, getInt(item));    
}
```

Above `getInt` method accepts a `MyItem` argument and returns an `int` result.

Here, #2 gives me a much lower latency compared to #1. Does anyone have an idea why or anything going wrong for me?

Comment: A claimed performance difference without documenting the measuring method is worthless. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2711488), I bet, you violated one rule or two. A helpful pointer might be the [Java lambdas 20 times slower than anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34585444/2711488) Q&A.

Comment: @Holger Are you suggesting me to put values with the method?

Comment: No, I’m suggesting to document how you came to the conclusion that your second code has “much lower latency” than the first. If we used measuring code instead of feelings, post that code. Then, we can tell you what you made wrong. Or you follow the already posted links and find out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList.stream().mapToInt(this::getInt).max()
```

Try [mapping to an `IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-). An `IntStream` works with `int`s internally, which avoids the overhead of boxing and unboxing `Integer` objects. Also, [`IntStream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) doesn't need a custom comparator.

> So you suggest that the prominent reason is 'boxing' and 'unboxing'?

Without running it through your benchmark I don't know if it'll match the `for` loop's performance. But it'll be an improvement. If it's not good enough then I suggest sticking with the loop as I don't see any other way to improve it.

Comment: I actually tried with the int stream way that you have suggested. But I couldn't actually see any notable performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take advantage of features of Streams, that should optimise these cases. Read the docs for Streams, the first example shows the optimised path for IntStream.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

```
     int max = myList.stream()
                      .mapToInt(this::getInt)
                      .max()
                      .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: I don't see any use of `.orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);` here. Am I missing anything?

Comment: sum() returns 0 for 0 elements, max() returns an OptionalInt.

Comment: `max()` returns an `OptionalInt` which is empty if there are no elements. It's better to stick with that than convert it to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @YuriSchimke your answer is helpful. However, doing in that way didn't give me any notable performance improvement