# Will the JVM be able to hoist a Java stream from within a loop?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jvm

I'm wondering if the JVM is able to hoist a stream out of a loop, for example in this intersection check that I wrote:

```
for (SomeObject someObject:someObjects) {
    if (someList.stream().map(SomeObject::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .contains(someObject.getValue())) {
        //do some error stuff
    }
}
```

Is it necessary for me to refactor it like so:

```
final List<Value> values = someList.stream().map(SomeObject::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (SomeObject someObject:someObjects) {
    if (values.contains(someObject.getValue()) {
        //do some error stuff
    }
}
```

It's probably nicer looking code this way, but I'm just wondering if it will have a big performance difference.

Comment: I see no reason why the first version would not work.  Have you tried it yet?  Note that you _could_ also rewrite the first `for` loop using `foreach`, if you are a real glutton for lambda expressions.

Comment: Do you need to process each overlapping item separately?  Or, would a single error message suffice?

Comment: @Tim both work fine, I'm just wondering about the performance impact of doing this over a large loop, and more generally what the JVM can and can't hoist

Comment: I think also using a Set and not a List would improve the performance, in the second code block

Comment: Good point @Matthieu

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the second code is way better, in the first one you were creating from scratch the stream for each 'SomeObject'.

Comment: This would be my intuition as well, but some preliminary testing doesn't show any difference in performance. Can you provide some evidence for why it needs to do that?

Comment: @AdamBeddoe The JVM/compiler might be smart enough to realize that your list from a stream is not correlated to the containing loop, and knows enough to pull it out and compute it only once.  But, the second version is what I think you should be using here.

Comment: @AdamBeddoe are you sure that your performance test is correct?
Maybe your compiler or JIT just moved stream out of loop for first code sample?

Comment: Intuitive stream solution would be something like: `if (someObjects.stream()
.anyMatch(someObject -> someList.stream()
.anyMatch(someListItem -> someListItem.getValue().equals(someObject.getValue())))
) { // do stuff; }`

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet "No". AFAIK the JVM does no interprocedural optimizations. There may be some exceptions, but basically, it only optimizes a single method at a time. For this to be really helpful, it relies on inlining, but your expression is far too complicated for inlining.

---

Anyway, your second snippet

```
final List<Value> values = someList.stream().map(SomeObject::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (SomeObject someObject:someObjects) {
    if (values.contains(someObject.getValue()) {
        //do some error stuff
    }
}
```

is not optimal either. With the stream inside the loop, you could use

```
...anyMatch(v -> v.equals(someObject.getValue())
```

to save yourself collecting. Or, better, you can use a `Set` for faster lookup.

Comment: The JVM definitely *does* “interprocedural optimizations”, known as performing “aggressive inlining” as the very first step before applying any other optimization. It would be disastrous if it didn’t. However, in this specific example, chances are high, that the overall code exceeds specific limits (maximum code size, maximum inlining depth) or hits a construct that prevents the full set of potential optimizations. The Stream implementation has quiet long call chains and Java 8’s limits are not up-to-date…

Comment: @Holger I see, I should reformulate my answer... AFAIK all these "interprocedural optimizations" are actually "aggressive inlining" followed by "intraprocedural optimizations". Or are there any exceptions, where the JVM can do something useful for a non-inlined method?

Comment: @Holger *agresive inlining*? Is this different that *inlining*? First time I hear about this? And also the code inside the JVM has been slightly adjusted to take into account for streams, I remember seing even comments for it

Comment: @Holger I think [this is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161545/can-hotspot-inline-lambda-function-calls)

Comment: @Eugene “Aggressive inlining” is an umbrella term for “speculative inlining”, “optimistic inlining”, and perhaps some other forms, which have in common that it is not guaranteed that the method invocation always ends up at the method that has been inlined, so fall-backs must be inserted to handle the other cases and even de-optimization may follow at a later time. It may also be used to emphasize that it is not applied merely for eliminating the invocation overhead, but to enable subsequent optimizations, which outweigh any invocation related costs.

Comment: @Holger something very new for me with speculative inline, thank you; will need to read about it more. As far as fall backs go, I know about these, at least I think so, that deoptimizations are possible, what zombie methods are, etc. Thank you for the insight

Comment: This article seems to show that the JVM will perform this sort of loop hoisting, but perhaps streams are far too complex for this sort of thing. https://advancedweb.hu/2016/06/28/jvm_jit_optimization_techniques_part_2/

Comment: Yes, done some proper benchmarks and the second version is significantly faster.