# Where's the code for a lambda located in a java class file?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, jvm, bytecode

I've this java source file:

```
import java.util.function.*;
public class t {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Function<Integer,Integer> r = (a) -> a*a+2*a+1;
      System.out.println(r.apply(2));
   }
}
```

I compile it and it works as expected. [Here](https://pastebin.com/rg9Wjk53)'s the output of `javap -c -v t`, and I can't find the location of lambda in it. Where's the bytecode which tells the jvm to compute the expression with the input `Integer` whenever the lambda is envoked?

Comment: `(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;` from the javap output, accept Integer parameter and return Integer

Comment: @HemantPatel Where's the code which tells jvm to compute the expression `a*a+2*a+1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see the code of your lambda body `a*a+2*a+1`, you should call `javap -c -v -p t` to see also the *private* methods:

```
private static java.lang.Integer lambda$main$0(java.lang.Integer);
descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
Code:
  stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
     4: aload_0
     5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
     8: imul
     9: iconst_2
    10: aload_0
    11: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
    14: imul
    15: iadd
    16: iconst_1
    17: iadd
    18: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    21: areturn
  LineNumberTable:
    line 4: 0
```

More detailed answer about the lambda inner implementation is here: [How will Java lambda functions be compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16827262/2886891)

Comment: You'll see these methods in stack traces. They are private static methods that start with the name 'lambda$'.