# Trying to mimic java functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-programming, functional-interface

I am trying to mimic the java's Function<T,R> by writing below code :

> ```
> interface SFunction<T, G> {
>     G apply(T t);
>
>     default <Q> SFunction<T, Q> andThen(SFunction<? super G, ? extends Q> after) {
>        return (T t) -> {
>             return after.apply(apply(t));
>         };
>         // return new SFunction<T, Q>() {
>         // @Override
>         // public Q apply(T t) {
>         // return after.apply(apply(t));
>         // }
>         // };
>     }
> }
> ```

when I am writing below code in `andThen`, it's working fine (pointing to `apply(T t)` of interface) and perfectly chaining the other functional implementations

```
snippet A return (T t) -> {
    return after.apply(apply(t));     
};
```

But when writing below snippet, it's falling into recursion, logically that's correct

```
snippet B return new SFunction<T, Q>() {
            @Override
            public Q apply(T t) {
                return after.apply(apply(t));
            }
        };
```

, but why in snippet A, `after.apply(apply(t))` is calling outer `apply(T t)` even though internally java implement the anonymous implementation.

Isn't snippet A and B same internally and logically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to note what method the `apply(t)` in snippet B is actually referring to:

```
@Override
public Q apply(T t) { // <--- it's referring to this method!
    return after.apply(apply(t));
//                     ^^^^^^^^
}
```

It is actually referring to the `apply(T)` method that returns a `Q` that you have just declared. It's trying to call it recursively. But obviously that doesn't work, because `after.apply` doesn't expect a `Q`. The declaration of the `Q apply(T)` method [*shadows*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the `G apply(T)` method declared outside.

In the lambda's case, you do not introduce a new identifier called `apply`, so `apply` can only mean the `apply` on the `SFunction<T, G>` object - the one on which `andThen` is called.

To refer to the `SFunction<T, G>` object's `apply` method in the `SFunction<T, Q>` anonymous class, you can use a qualified `this` expression:

```
return after.apply(SFunction.this.apply(t));
```

`SFunction.this` refers to the `SFunction<T, G>` object on which `andThen` is called.

Now the two versions are logically the same, but internally, [lambdas are very different from anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827262/how-will-java-lambda-functions-be-compiled).