Classes defined by using lambda in Java
I had a test on OOP in Java and they asked how many classes are defined by the code below.
The question is about the lambda expression in this code. The lambda expression initiates an anonymous class, but here the expression is in a for loop that iterates 3 times. Does this create 3 classes or just one class?
If it matters, we are working with Java 17.
I've tried to ask Chat GPT but it is unreliable and I've tried to search for an answer, but I can't find a complete and specific answer online.
public interface AI {
     int f();
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AI ai;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int j = i;
            ai = () -> j + 2;
        }
    }

}


Proper formatting of your code will attract more readers.

You can test it yourself. Compile the program and you'll see it creates just one class for the lambda. This class is created at compile time. Are you actually asking how many instances will be created?

kind of confusing, mixed: "classes defined", "initiates 3 classes"... that code declares one class - Main; creates a second one at runtime - Main$$Lambda/0x....l and probably instantiates three instances of that second one (since using j)

Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827262/how-will-java-lambda-functions-be-compiled

Your line of reasoning is highly confused.
Given:
class Dog {
  String name;
}

void test() {
  Dog a = new Dog();
  Dog b = new Dog();
  Dog c = new Dog();
  Dog d = new Dog();
}

surely you wouldn't say that '4 classes are defined here, because 4 classes are instantiated'. And yet you are applying that logic to your lambdas here. That is, obviously, wrong.

lambda expressions initiates an anonymous class

This is simply false. It's a way to explain lambdas, and a particularly useful way about 12 years ago when lambdas were introduced (lambdas weren't part of java until java v1.8 - decades of java preceded them!), as, until then, solving the problems that lambdas can solve for you required anonymous inner classes.
It does not mean, and never has meant, that lambdas are just syntax sugar for inner classes. This is literally the case: A lambda simply does not result in a class. How the compiler ends up making a class file that does what you need it to is up to the compiler, but at time of writing, the JDK generally generates a method that contains the 'body' of the lambda and just invokes it if that's all you are doing with the lambda, or makes a methodhandle to refer to it if it needs to be passed around.
Thus, reading 'how many classes are defined' in some sort of 'at the JVM level' results in the following answer, and this is the only correct answer! (I can imagine a teacher would disagree. That'd be because they are wrong! Feel free to send them to this answer):
That is not answerable; the Java Lang Spec does not dictate any particular implementation. At least one (Main). AI defines an interface which isn't a class, but, at the JVM level, 'types' is the better word, and certainly at least 2 types are being set up here. Maybe a 3rd - up to the compiler.
If the question is about the java side of things, the answer is much simpler:
1 class is being defined (Main), and 1 interface (AI). Period. Classes are defined with class and with the anonymous inner class literal. lambdas are neither of those. The spec literally spells this out. The spec's pages about lambdas don't mention 'this defines a class' anywhere in them.

Thanks for the detailed explanation.
Can you please explain this article? How does that fit with your claims?

@ToharYahakovCohen that’s not the way we ask questions here. If you think, this article contradicts the statement, explain what contradiction you see. Then, we can address it.

@ToharYahakovCohen A quick scroll through that does not indicate anything that stands out as contradicting this answer. As Holger said - what are you talking about? Quote a line or two.

Sorry about that, I'm new here.
I read the article again and realized I just thought there was a contradiction, thank you very much.

@TYC No problem. If there are any sections of that article that clash or appear to be somewhat at odds with this, I can edit the answer, quote a section, and elaborate a bit if that would help, just let me know.

public interface AI {
     int f();
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AI ai;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int j = i;
            ai = () -> j + 2;
        }
    }

}

How many classes are defined by this code?  Two.  AI and Main.  Lambdas aren't classes or anonymous classes.  They're implemented as something much more complex.
How many objects are allocated by this code?  It's not specified.  The machinery involved in creating lambdas is likely to allocate a very large number of objects, none of which are obvious.  The class that's likely to be created for the lambda at runtime should get reused for each loop, though.  It's not likely that the lambda object itself is reused, since it captures j, but it's also legal for the compiler to eliminate the for loop entirely.

To add fuel to the flames, some people consider classes and interface distinct entities while others consider interfaces to be special classes. We need to read the exam’s author’s mind to get the expected answer. There’s also the point of view that this code does define another class in that it specifies which interface this class has to fulfill und what behavior the functional method ought to have. Even if that doesn’t imply that a materialized class with those properties has to exist, as long as the execution has the expected behavior. In short, such exam questions are not useful.
