# is this partial function a closure?

Tags: clojure, closures

I am discussing closure with a friend and he thinks `(partial + 5)` is a closure. But I think a closure is a function closing over a free variable, for example

```
(let [a 10]
  (defn func1 [x] (+ x a))
)
```

then `func1` is a closure. But in this case `5` is not a free variable. So which is the right answer?

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct in terms of implementation, I'd argue that it shouldn't be considered a closure, but rather "just" a partial application. The use of a closure is an internal implementation detail that is not directly exposed to the caller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`partial` uses a closure to make the partial function. Check out the code of `partial` by using `(source partial)` in repl and you will see that it uses closures.

```
(defn partial
  "Takes a function f and fewer than the normal arguments to f, and
  returns a fn that takes a variable number of additional args. When
  called, the returned function calls f with args + additional args."
  {:added "1.0"}
  ([f arg1]
   (fn [& args] (apply f arg1 args)))
  ([f arg1 arg2]
   (fn [& args] (apply f arg1 arg2 args)))
  ([f arg1 arg2 arg3]
   (fn [& args] (apply f arg1 arg2 arg3 args)))
  ([f arg1 arg2 arg3 & more]
   (fn [& args] (apply f arg1 arg2 arg3 (concat more args)))))
```

Comment: Why is it written like that? I'm just learning right now and [f arg1] seems redundant since there is a "varargs" implementation (the one with &more)

Comment: A safe bet would be it's optimizing the most common cases

Answer (score 0):

`(partial + 5)` is an anonymous function or "lambda".

Anonymous functions are often¹ called "closures" but it's an abuse of the term ; see the discussion in ["What is the difference between a 'closure' and a 'lambda'?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/220658/2608009)

---

[¹] Maybe because in most popular languages that support them, closures and anonymous functions are created using the same language features - which renders them undistinguishable at first glance.