# Tkinter Menu command targets function with arguments?

Tags: python, tkinter, command, tk-toolkit

I'm wondering, how would I make a Tkinter (in Python) Menu that targets a function with arguments, such as `foo("what")`?

```
def foo(arg):
    print "Foo, %s." % arg

popup = Menu()
popup.add_command(label="Spam!", command=foo("spam")) # Doesn't work.
popup.add_command(label="Turkey!", command=foo("turkey")) # Doesn't work.
popup.post(50, 50)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Command takes a function as argument, but `foo("spam")` gives the return value of `foo` when called with argument `"spam"`. As a solution, you can use an anonymous function which calls `foo("spam")` as argument:

```
command=lambda: foo("spam")
```

Answer (score 7):

For this kind of stuff, especially event handlers and commands, an elegant solution is using the `functools` module's `partial()` method.

```
from functools import partial
...
command=partial(foo, "spam")
```

Partial is said to be faster than using lambda: [Differences between functools.partial and a similar lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828410/differences-between-functools-partial-and-a-similar-lambda)

Comment: This approach seems to be the only one that works when, instead of `"spam"`, we have an iteration variable. E.g. `for elem in list : ... command=partial(foo, elem)` won't work using `lambda`.

Comment: @horcrux You can use lambda inside a loop, but you need to bind the current loop value to a keyword argument in your lambda. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677768/3714930