# Java 8 forEach Loop Takes much time, why?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList around 3483 object that ready to merge in database.
When I use lambda expressions - it takes 85122 ms.
But `for(Obj o : list)` takes only 25 ms. Why Java8 takes 3404 times more time ?

```
List<CIBSubjectData> list1 = .....

list1.forEach(data ->
     merge(data)
);

for (CIBSubjectData data : list1) {
    merge(data);
}
```

Comment: Tried the parallel stream: list1.parallelStream().forEach(data -> merge(data)) ?

Comment: you might find your answer int [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop).

Comment: I think we'll need more context and/or code here. `forEach`+lambda does take longer, but nowhere near *that* much longer, in the general case. I just did a trivial check (which is [not reliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)) on a `LinkedList` with 400k entries, `forEach` took 40ms; enhanced `for` look 5ms.

Comment: What do you do inside `merge(data)`?

Answer (score 3):

I belive you are not using a proper microbenchmark setting. You are comparing the warmup of the `bytecode instrumentation framework` (ASM which is used to generated the lambda bytecode at **runtime**) + `lambda execution time` with the `execution time of the loop`.

Check this answer for [performance-difference-between-java-8-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294846/performance-difference-between-java-8-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classes#24294935) and the linked document. The linked document has a deep insight about the processing under the hood.

**edit** To provide a small snippet to demonstrate the above.

```
public class Warmup {
    static int dummy;

    static void merge(String s) {
        dummy += s.length();
        dummy++;
        dummy -= s.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rand = new Random(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
            list1.add(Long.toString(rand.nextLong()));
        }

        // this will boostrap the bytecode instrumentation
        // Stream.of("foo".toCharArray()).forEach(System.out::println);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        list1.forEach(data -> merge(data));

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("duration: %d%n", end - start);
        System.out.println(dummy);
    }
}
```

If you run the code as it is posted the printed duration on my machine is

```
duration: 71694425
```

If you uncomment the line `Stream.of(...` (which is only there to use the the bytecode instrumentation framework the first time) the printed duration is

```
duration: 7516086
```

Which is only around 10% of the initial run.

**note** Only to be explicit. Don't use benchmarks like the above. Have a look at [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for such a requirement.

Comment: OP reports "85122 ms"; that's one and a half minutes. I would not call this "microbenchmarking", and don't think that it's all due to warm-up, either...

Comment: @tobias_k I agree. But `for(Obj o : list) takes only 25 ms` it is. So he for sure want's to make a microbenchmark. Otherwise the loop would also take much longer. For the point that lambda take much longer. We need more input from the OP.