# using Supplier in CompletableFuture yields different result than using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I have created a small example of reading a text file and wrap the call with `CompletableFuture`.

```
public class Async {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<String> result = ReadFileUsingLambda(Paths.get("path/to/file"));
        result.whenComplete((ok, ex) -> {
            if (ex == null) {
                System.out.println(ok);
            } else {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<String> ReadFileUsingSupplier(Path file) throws Exception {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<String>() {
            @Override
            public String get() {
                try {
                    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "test";
                }
            }
        }, ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }

    public static CompletableFuture<String> ReadFileUsingLambda(Path file) throws Exception {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "test";
            }
        } , ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
    }
}
```

This code returns nothing. It executes and "nothing happens", no errors or output. If I call `ReadFileUsingSupplier` instead of `ReadFileUsingLambda` then I get the file content printed in the console!

To me this doesn't make sense because a lambda is a shorthand for writing an inline function and it shouldn't change the behaviour but in this example it does apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of execution timing - the lambda may take a little more to execute, allowing the program to exit before you are done reading the file.

Try this:

- add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` as the first statement within the try block in `ReadFileUsingSupplier` and you won't see any output
- add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` at the end of your main when using `ReadFileUsingLambda` and you will see the expected output

To make sure your main doesn't exit before the future is completed, you can call:

```
result.join();
```

Comment: thank you. This did the trick but going forward how can I make sure that my program doesn't exit until I get the result back from CompletableFuture

Comment: @SulAga You can simply call `result.get()` or `result.join()`

Comment: So the join or get is a blocking call? is it a blocking on the main thread or on CompletableFuture thread? is this a problem i.e. blocking

Comment: @SulAga It's blocking on the thread from which it's called - if you just add `result.join()` at the end of `main`, it will block the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you need to result.join() in either case to avoid the main thread exiting too quickly.

It seems that there's a penalty for using lambdas vs anonymous closures while the JVM warms up, thereafter the performance is the same. I found this information at on [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294935/1492059) - which in turn links [a performance study by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013kuksen-2014088.pdf).

As a sidenote it's not a great idea to Thread.sleep() to fix weird timing issues, ever. Figuring out the cause and applying the appropriate measures would be much clearer when re-read by you or by others, e.g.

```
System.out.println(result.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

This enables you to ditch the .join(), too.