# Difference between lambda expression and anonymous implementation of Comparator for Arrays.sort?

Tags: java, lambda, comparator, anonymous-class

Suppose I have an array in `Java`:

```
int[][] arr = new int[n][2];
```

and I want to sort it, for example, according to the first value of the second dimension, thus for every element `i`, `arr[i][0]`.

I saw that in `Java`, there exist two similar ways of doing it, and I want to know what the difference is (efficiency, when to use which method,...).

**Method 1)**

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> {
  a[0] - b[0];
});
```

**Method 2)**

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<int[]>(){
  @Override
  public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
  }
};
```

**Alternative method:**

```
class Test implements Comparable<Test>{
  int val0, val1;
  // Contructor
  public int compareTo(Test t) {
    return val0.compareTo(t.val0);
  }
}
```

And then using in the main method:

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

where arr is:

```
Test[] arr = new int[n];
```

Here `val0` and `val1` are respectively the 0'th and 1st value of the second dimension. I would not create a class to compare one value, but I sometimes use it for more complex systems and this is anyway an other way of creating a comparator, and if I measure the computational time, it is faster, do you know why?

The question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452429/java-arrays-sort-2d-array) because it is not asking how to compare. It is also different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637900/java8-lambdas-vs-anonymous-classes), because it takes into account also the *Alternative method* of class definition. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294846/performance-difference-between-java-8-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classes) one is not specifying about comparing.

Comment: If you google "anonymous class vs lambda" you'll probably get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks to @Carcigenicate's suggestion, here is a helpful link : [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294935/2928853) -> [PDF containing the answer](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013kuksen-2014088.pdf)

Comment: This “using minus for a comparator” antipattern is really tenacious. Don’t use minus. Minus can overflow. There’s `Integer.compare(int,int)` for your convenience when implementing a comparator manually, but you rarely need it, just use `Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0]));`. But what’s your question?