# Lambda expression and equivalent anonymous class

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class

If I have a method that takes a single-method interface as an argument, I can call it like this:

```
foo(new Bar() {
    @Override
    public String baz(String qux) {
        return modify(qux) + transmogrify(qux);
    }
}
```

But if I have to call `foo` millions of times in a tight loop, I might prefer to avoid creating a new instance of the anonymous class every time through the loop:

```
final Bar bar = new Bar() {
        @Override
        public String baz(String qux) {
            return modify(qux) + transmogrify(qux);
        }
    };

while (...) {
    foo(bar);
}
```

Now if I replace the anonymous class with a lambda expression:

```
while (...) {
    foo(qux -> modify(qux) + transmogrify(qux));
}
```

Is this lambda expression equivalent to the first or second snippet from the above examples of anonymous class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294846/performance-difference-between-java-8-lambdas-and-anonymous-inner-classes

Comment: It's probably worth notnig that _officially_ it's more similar to the first, in that it will call `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory...` _within_ the loop (similar to how that would call `<init>` within the loop).  However that doesn't mean the performance is worse, after JIT starts doing its thing.  Additionally, you can declare your `Bazer` (whatever that method comes from) via a lambda outside of the loop in the latter case anyway.

Comment: You can also do this btw.
*final Function<String, String> func = str -> modify(str) + transmogrify(str);*
then *System.out.println(func.apply("rooster"));*

Comment: There are more options. If the while iterates a collection or iterable, I would use forEach with the call to foo and the lambda in it. If it's not a collection, you can assign the lambda to a Function variable before the loop and use that variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think it's more like the second one because there will only be one instance of `Bar` created by the lambda.**

I write a Test class:

```
public class LambdaTest {
    //create a new runnable for each loop
    void test1(){
        while (true){
            invoke(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("---");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //create only one Runnable
    void test2(){
        Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("---");
            }
        };
        while (true){
            invoke(runnable);
        }
    }

    //use lambda
    void test3(){
        while (true){
            invoke(()->{
                System.out.println("---");
            });
        }
    }
    private void invoke(Runnable runnable){
    }
}
```

And here is the bytecode for each method:

```
test1:
         0: aload_0
         1: new           #2                  // class LambdaTest$1
         4: dup
         5: aload_0
         6: invokespecial #3                  // Method LambdaTest$1."<init>":(LLambdaTest;)V
         9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method invoke:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        12: goto          0

test2:
         0: new           #5                  // class LambdaTest$2
         3: dup
         4: aload_0
         5: invokespecial #6                  // Method LambdaTest$2."<init>":(LLambdaTest;)V
         8: astore_1
         9: aload_0
        10: aload_1
        11: invokevirtual #4                  // Method invoke:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        14: goto          9

test3:
         0: aload_0
         1: invokedynamic #7,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:run:()Ljava/lang/Runnable;
         6: invokevirtual #4                  // Method invoke:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
         9: goto          0
```

In test1, each loop will crate a new instance of the anonymous class and call init method.
In test2, there will only be one instance of the anonymous class, and has the smallest number of opcode in the loop.
In test3, the only difference between test2 is that there add a `invokedynamic` before `invokevirtual` opcode in the loop.

According the this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-invoke-dynamic#3-the-problem), `invokedynamic` will call a bootstrap method to create an instance of the anonymous class for the first time, after that it will use the created instance for the rest of its life.

So my suggestion is: **Use lambda when ever you like, don't have to care about the overhead.**