# How to store string value in local variable using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using java 8 stream features now i want to store string value in local variable,but its showing `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`.I also tried final keyword its getting same.I need clarification its possible or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = Arrays.asList("java", "stream", "scala");
        String data = "";
        list.forEach(action -> {
            data = action.toString();
            System.out.println("data :" + data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need `data` outside lambda? it seems you can remove the variable

Comment: Even if it was possible, what's the point? you overwrite the value of `data` with each element of the List, so it would have the last element in the end. Do you wish to concatenate all these `String`s? If you do, there are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: yes i need outside lambda.whatever i stored in list. For ex : data=java

Comment: Show what you do with `data` outside lambda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - changing the value of a final variable from within a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851892/java-changing-the-value-of-a-final-variable-from-within-a-lambda)

Comment: Why would you wanna store it if you are going to overwrite it anyway? Wouldn't it always be the case in this List iteration you are going to end up with data as ``` "scala" ```? What are you doing to do by storing this anyway?

Comment: @ Siddarth Sreeni I need only store any values from list outside lambda.

Comment: what do you want to do with that variable ? @AjithDeivam and why

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("java", "stream", "scala");
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
list.forEach(action -> {
    data.replace(0, data.length(), action);
    System.out.println("data :" + data);
});


Although I **don't** recommend it.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will try to reinitialize final variable, It will throw error.

I suggest you to use arraylist/list/array as final and add value to list , example as below

```
final ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        List list = Arrays.asList("java", "stream", "scala");
        list.forEach(action -> {
            strings.add(action.toString());

        });
```