# Higher order function and closure in java

Tags: java, java-8, closures

The following code mimics both higher ordered function and closure.

```
static Function<Integer, Integer> getDoubleFunc(int multi) {
    return (val) -> {
        return val * multi;
    };
}
```

But why it's not considered as one? Is it because Function here is an interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not considered as one"? What is your concern?

Comment: I saw a deck by Bruce Eckel in which he said about java 8 not supporting closure.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17204279/1743880

Answer (score 6):

The whole "debate" about whether Java lambda expressions are "real closures" or not is a pretty unproductive one, because most participants are implicitly defining what "real closure" means in terms of what their favorite other language calls closures, and then turning around and saying "Language Y doesn't have 'real' closures."

Java lambda expressions close over *values* in the enclosing lexical scope, but not over *variables*.

Wikipedia says: "a closure is a record storing a function together with an environment, which is a mapping associating each free variable of the function (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope) with the **value** or storage location to which the name was bound when the closure was created." (emphasis added).