# How Is This Function Working? I Can't Understand Exactly What is Going On

Tags: php, slim

Here is a function definition of Set `Helper` class

```
public function singleton($key, $value)
    {
        $this->set($key, function ($c) use ($value) {
            static $object;

            if (null === $object) {
                $object = $value($c);
            }

            return $object;
        });
    }
```

and in this class the above mentioned function will be called like

```
 // Default environment
        $this->container->singleton('environment', function ($c) {
            return \Slim\Environment::getInstance();
        });
```

where `$this->container` represents the `Set` helper class.

Comment: Do you know what Singleton is?

Comment: Yes I know what singelton is. But I am not comfortable with Closure functions in PHP

Comment: We needed to know that before trying to explain what is going on.

Comment: OK, thank you very much and waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an example of singleton factory using a plugin-strategy.

The API user declares "When I ask for the `environment` object, use the function `function ($c) { return Slim\Environment::getInstance() }` to generate it."  The `singleton` method then takes care to ensure the API user only ever gets back the single instance of the `environment` object.

Mechanically, the `singleton` method associates a closure with a key.  The closure manufactures a singleton object, given an anonymous function plug-in to actually do the instantiation.  `$value` is the anonymous function and is responsible for whatever needs to go on to generate an instance of the object to become a singleton.  `singleton` is responsible for ensuring that instantiation is every called once.

Side note: the [difference between a closure and an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda) is meaninful in understanding what's going on with this method.