# Why is Java Lambda also called Closures

Tags: java, java-8

I am currently going through the Java Lambda and find it is also called Closures.

Please is there a reason why it is also called Closures? I want a technical explanation.

Comment: Try next time to use the search function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are two different terms that happen to often be mentioned in the same context.

- A **lambda** is basically just an anonymous function. Example: `() -> System.out.println("Hello")`. It's a function, but it doesn't have a name.
- A **closure** is a term regarding scoping. When you for instance refer to a local variable inside a lambda, as follows

  ```
  int localInt = 17;

  saveThisFunction(() -> System.out.println(localInt));
  ```

  you create a closure to *capture* `localInt` inside the lambda. Textually it looks obvious that it should be ok to access `localInt` inside the lambda, but keep in mind that the lambda can be stored and called long after the `localInt` has been popped from the stack.

So, creating a lambda expression often requires creating a closure (implicitly).

Answer (score 4):

Technically it's wrong, lambda expressions and closures are two slightly different things.

**Lambdas** are anonymous functions, that in the Java world take the form of anonymous single method classes (see also [functional interfaces](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/)):

```
Runnable r1 = () -> System.out.println("I'm Runnable");
```

**Closures** are a specific sub-type of lambda expressions where local variables have been binded to variables defined in a specific enclosing environment.

In the Java world, you are just writing something similar to this example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables):

```
final int x = 99;
        
Consumer<Integer> myConsumer = (y) -> 
{
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
};
```

For a more complete abstract definition of closures:

> Operationally, a closure is a data structure storing a function together with an environment: a mapping associating each free variable of the function (**variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope**) with the value or storage location the name was bound to at the time the closure was created.
>
> A closure—unlike a plain function—allows the function to access those captured variables through the closure's reference to them, *even when the function is invoked outside their scope*.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

And that last part means that you can do this:

```
public class Funct{


    public static Consumer<Integer> getThatClosure(){
        final int x = 99;

        Consumer<Integer> myConsumer = (y) -> 
        {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("y = " + y);
        };
        return myConsumer;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        Consumer<Integer> cons=getThatClosure();
        cons.accept(0);
    }

}
```

With this output:

```
x=99
y=0
```

Answer (score -2):

simply because the terms are equivalent (I think as well as "anonymous function") and this is how similar mechanism is being called in different languages, e.g. Groovy has closures

btw, I don't think this is right board to ask such questions

Comment: The terms are absolutely not equivalent.