# Possibility to use ListFilter in a cffunction

Tags: coldfusion, closures

I have a list and want to remove some elements in a function. I pass the elements I want to remove into that function as a structure. I thought I can use the function `ListFilter` to iterate through the list. Since I pass a function as argument into this function, I now wonder if it's possible to access the `Arguments` scope of my `cffunction` from the closure. Can this closure access any "external" variables?  In what scope do these have to reside?

```cfm
<cffunction name="funcA" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="struExcludeCols" type="struct">

    <cfset local.strLst = "Listel1,Listel2,Listel3">

    <cfscript>
        local.columnNames = ListFilter( 
            strLst, 
            function( strCol ) {             
                return not StructKeyExists( Arguments.struExcludeCols, strCol );       
            } 
        );
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn local.columnNames>
</cffunction>


<cfdump var="#funcA( { "Listel2" = 1 } )#">
```

Comment: What do you mean by `closure`?

Comment: @DanBracuk Closure is the "inline function" I pass to `ListFilter` as second argument.

Comment: Just see this stackoverflow posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda `A closure [...] can access variables not in its parameter list`. This does not work in my case, so it's not a closure. ;) A `lambda` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline function from within `ListFilter` does not have access to the `Arguments` scope of `funcA`. It does have access to `this`.

*Working code:*

```
<cffunction name="funcA" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="struExcludeCols" type="struct">

    <cfset local.strLst = "Listel1,Listel2,Listel3">
    <cfset this.struExcludeCols = Arguments.struExcludeCols>

    <cfscript>
        local.columnNames = ListFilter( 
            strLst, 
            function( strCol ) {             
                return not StructKeyExists( this.struExcludeCols, strCol );       
            } 
        );
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn local.columnNames>
</cffunction>


<cfdump var="#funcA( { "Listel2" = 1 } )#">
```

Comment: `this` is the global private scope of the cfc. Wouldn't want to pollute it but answers my question. Thank you!